# Insert HTML into view from AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, escaping, html-sanitizing

Is it possible to create an **HTML** fragment in an AngularJS controller and have this HTML shown in the view?

This comes from a requirement to turn an inconsistent JSON blob into a nested list of `id: value` pairs. Therefore the **HTML** is created in the controller and I am now looking to display it.

I have created a model property, but cannot render this in the view without it just printing the **HTML**.

---

Update

It appears that the problem arises from angular rendering the created HTML as a string within quotes. Will attempt to find a way around this.

Example controller :

```
var SomeController = function () {

    this.customHtml = '<ul><li>render me please</li></ul>';
}
```

Example view :

```
<div ng:bind="customHtml"></div>
```

Gives :

```
<div>
    "<ul><li>render me please</li></ul>"
</div>
```

Comment: Also please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711735/angular-js-insert-html-with-scripts-that-should-run), asking if it's possible to get scripts in inserted HTML to run.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple objects bound to the same ng-bind? like 
```
ng-bind="site.address_1 site.address_2 site.zip"

Comment: Sorry, the chosen answer by Luke may not be the totally right answer. The right answer can be found in another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18157958/2197555). Basically, "ng-bind-html-unsafe only renders the content as HTML. It doesn't bind Angular scope to the resulted DOM. You have to use $compile service for that purpose."

Comment: ng-bind removes all internal html. which is not how filter would work, it's ok when filter is the only value

Comment: As of Angular 4, this is the way that now works: <div [innerHTML]="htmlString"> </div> Taken from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding/34424375#34424375

Answer (score 1155, accepted):

For Angular 1.x, use `ng-bind-html` in the HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html="thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml"></div>
```

At this point you would get a `attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context` error so you need to either use [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) or [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to resolve that.

#### $sce

Use `$sce.trustAsHtml()` in the controller to convert the html string.

```
 $scope.thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(someHtmlVar);
```

#### ngSanitize

There are 2 steps:

1. include the angular-sanitize.min.js resource, i.e.:

   ```
   <script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. In a js file (controller or usually app.js), include ngSanitize, i.e.:

   ```
   angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 
       'myApp.directives', 'ngSanitize'])
   ```

Comment: In Angular 1.2, `ng-bind-html-unsafe` was removed and the two directives were combined. See: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120-rc1-spooky-giraffe-2013-08-13

Comment: Without using ngSanitize, it can be done now by using `$sce`. Inject it into the controller and pass the html through it. `$scope.thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(someHtmlVar);` Otherwise I kept getting `attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context`

Comment: We need a bit of a cleanup here which is the right way nothing seems to be working for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829275/angular-js-shows-html-within-the-tag <-- worked for me :) none of the options in the answers here worked unfortunately

Comment: What if html needs to be inserted into html tag attribute?

Comment: Just so people aren't disheartened, the latest update of this answer, coupled with the ngSanitize requirement at the bottom of the answer, does in fact work.

Comment: 1) ng-bind-html and then 2) sce.trustAsHtml() .... Is there a way to do it in one step?

Comment: Thank you very much. This post saved me a lot of time. Just a note to not forget to include the dependencies, as shown here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Comment: Soi what are the required steps to acheiveing the goal?

Comment: used the $sce method and it worked great for me. don't forget to add  ng-bind-html="thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml" to your element to generate your content.

Comment: Hello XSS :) be sure the content is trusted, not user input for example

Comment: but it does override all existing html so not as useful as filter

Comment: my $scope is not working inside html {{test}} any solution??

Comment: this works: <div [innerHtml]="someVariableInTheScope"></div>

Comment: ngSanitize option worked perfectly for me with Angularjs 1.6 version

Comment: Working Answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829275/angular-js-shows-html-within-the-tag

Answer (score 318):

You can also create a filter like so:

```
var app = angular.module("demoApp", ['ngResource']);

app.filter("trust", ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(htmlCode){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
  }
}]);
```

Then in the view

```
<div ng-bind-html="trusted_html_variable | trust"></div>
```

**Note**:  This filter trusts any and all html passed to it, and could present an XSS vulnerability if variables with user input are passed to it.

Comment: @Katie Astrauskas, thank you for the anwer! Very clean way. BTW `ngResource` dependency is not neccesary.

Comment: Only use this when you completely trust the HTML. This does not sanitize the HTML in any way, but only allows Angular to inject it into the page. Malicious HTML can provoke XSS attacks.

Comment: If performance is important, you should avoid using filters. A filter will trigger two digests each time.

Comment: Why is the filter called `sanitize`? This is so misleading as it doesn't actually sanitize anything. Instead it should be called `trust`,  `trustSafe` or something similar.

Comment: Wonderful answer. `rawHtml` is my name for the filter instead of `sanitize`.

Comment: @Katie indeed, ['ngResource'] dependency not needed for this, its not a fully sanitation.

Comment: can this be used like: {{ whatever_needs_to_be_sanitized | sanitize }} instead of bound to the element?

Answer (score 124):

[Angular JS shows HTML within the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829275/angular-js-shows-html-within-the-tag)

The solution provided in the above link worked for me, none of the options on this thread did. For anyone looking for the same thing with AngularJS version 1.2.9

Here's a copy:

> Ok I found solution for this:
>
> JS:
>
> ```
> $scope.renderHtml = function(html_code)
> {
>     return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
> };
> ```
>
> HTML:
>
> ```
> <p ng-bind-html="renderHtml(value.button)"></p>
> ```

EDIT:

Here's the set up:

JS file:

```
angular.module('MyModule').controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce',
    function ($scope, $http, $sce) {
        $scope.renderHtml = function (htmlCode) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
        };

        $scope.body = '<div style="width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid blue;"></div>'; 

    }]);
```

HTML file:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-bind-html="renderHtml(body)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be aware that you need to be absolutely sure that the html can be trusted. Otherwise the door is wide open for XSS attacks.

Comment: This solution, using a function to render the HTML, is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: what is the '$http' for?

Comment: @SoldeplataSaketos nothing in particular, I think I was trying it locally at the time and I ended up copying the dependency over.

Comment: Same answer update here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829275/angular-js-shows-html-within-the-tag

Comment: However, if the trusted HTML contains Javascript, it still does not work fully.

Answer (score 67):

Fortunately, you don't need any fancy filters or unsafe methods to avoid that error message. This is the complete implementation to properly output HTML markup in a view in the intended and safe way.

The sanitize module must be included after Angular:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Then, the module must be loaded:

```
angular.module('app', [
  'ngSanitize'
]);
```

This will allow you to include markup in a string from a controller, directive, etc:

```
scope.message = "<strong>42</strong> is the <em>answer</em>.";
```

Finally, in a template, it must be output like so:

```
<p ng-bind-html="message"></p>
```

Which will produce the expected output: **42** is the *answer*.

Comment: Try some html like `<div><label>Why My Input Element Missing</label><input /></div>`... If it surprises u then update your answer plz.. Because I tested all 10+vote solutions.. Your solution did'nt work for me to see my input tags.. fine otherwise.. I had use `$sce.trustAsHtml(html)`

Comment: This solution works, care to post a jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: This should really be the answer if using latest angular

Answer (score 63):

I have tried today, the only way I found was this

`<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="expression"></div>`

Comment: This solution should be used only if the source is trustful to avoid cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: As of Angular 1.0.2, this works for me, with no other files or hookup required.

Comment: Using Angular 1.0.8 and this worked for me.  Heed @Bertrand's warning though, be sure you trust the source.

Comment: For future reference ng-bind-html-unsafe was removed in the version 1.2. Now you need the ngSanitize module and to bind unsafe html you should use the $sce.trustAsHtml method.

Answer (score 54):

`ng-bind-html-unsafe` no longer works.

This is the shortest way:

**Create a filter:**

```
myApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

**And in your view:**

```
<div ng-bind-html="customHtml | unsafe"></div>
```

P.S. This method doesn't require you to include the `ngSanitize` module.

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen here for Angular 1.2. The solution using `$sce` in the accepted answer didn't work for me and I didn't want to include a additional dependency for something so trivial.

Comment: The solution by Bidhan Bhattarai worked for me.  Angular 1.6.1

Answer (score 27):

on html

```
<div ng-controller="myAppController as myCtrl">

<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="myCtrl.comment.msg"></div>
```

OR

```
<div ng-bind-html="myCtrl.comment.msg"></div
```

on controller

```
mySceApp.controller("myAppController", function myAppController( $sce) {

this.myCtrl.comment.msg = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
```

works also with `$scope.comment.msg = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);`

Comment: `$sce` is neat but couldn't a user just add a breakpoint here and restore any malicious code to `this.myCtrl.comment.msg` using a debugger?

Comment: then again BradGreens, would you be able to do the same with ng-bind-html-unsafe as well?

Comment: If someone wants to hack there own browser they can, who cares.  It won't effect other users. @BradGreens Is that the question?

Comment: @ChrisStephens you're correct. I guess that does answer my question but my opinion is these features are closer to perceived security than real security. Perhaps it protects against some kind of automated attacks? I've never clearly grasped why doing this things really helps the app. My app has to add a filter to EVERY instance of rendering wysiwyg HTML because it could have inline CSS, which `ng-bind-html` strips out.

Comment: Well these features help with reducing secure coding mistakes. In particular the issue with markup/code injection. By default all bound data is encoded for display.  So basically if you want to output markup this forces you to think about what you are trying to do. Without these features you can do a lot with server side security alone but to separate concerns the client app should charge of handling the data correctly for display.

Comment: appreciate the insight

Answer (score 9):

I found that using ng-sanitize did not allow me to add ng-click in the html.

To solve this I added a directive. Like this:

```
app.directive('htmldiv', function($compile, $parse) {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch(attr.content, function() {
      element.html($parse(attr.content)(scope));
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }, true);
  }
}
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<htmldiv content="theContent"></htmldiv>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Just did this using ngBindHtml by following [angular(v1.4) docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml),

```
<div ng-bind-html="expression"></div> 
and expression can be "<ul><li>render me please</li></ul>"
```

Make sure you include ngSanitize in the module's dependencies.
Then it should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, very similar to blrbr's except using a scoped attribute is:

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('renderHtml', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        html: '='
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

          function appendHtml() {
              if(scope.html) {
                  var newElement = angular.element(scope.html);
                  $compile(newElement)(scope);
                  element.append(newElement);
              }
          }

          scope.$watch(function() { return scope.html }, appendHtml);
      }
    };
  }]);
```

And then

```
<render-html html="htmlAsString"></render-html>
```

Note you may replace `element.append()` with `element.replaceWith()`

Answer (score 3):

you can also use ***ng-include***.

```
<div class="col-sm-9 TabContent_container" ng-include="template/custom.html">
</div>
```

you can use ***"ng-show"*** to show hide this template data.

Comment: You sure that this is all you need todo in order to use ng-include?

Comment: yes .. i have tried it out. and if you are using template then use it it the following way -
<script type="text/ng-template" id="custom.html">

Answer (score 3):

there is one more solution for this problem using creating new **attribute or directives** in angular.

***product-specs.html***

```
 <h4>Specs</h4>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <strong>Shine</strong>
            : {{product.shine}}</li>
          <li>
            <strong>Faces</strong>
            : {{product.faces}}</li>
          <li>
            <strong>Rarity</strong>
            : {{product.rarity}}</li>
          <li>
            <strong>Color</strong>
            : {{product.color}}</li>
        </ul>
```

***app.js***

```
 (function() {
var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);    
app.directive("     <div ng-show="tab.isSet(2)" product-specs>", function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: "product-specs.html"
};
});
```

***index.html***

```
 <div>
 <product-specs>  </product-specs>//it will load product-specs.html file here.
 </div>
```

or

```
<div  product-specs>//it will add product-specs.html file
```

or

```
<div ng-include="product-description.html"></div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 3):

here is the solution make a filter like this

```
.filter('trusted',
   function($sce) {
     return function(ss) {
       return $sce.trustAsHtml(ss)
     };
   }
)
```

and apply this as a filter to the ng-bind-html like

```
<div ng-bind-html="code | trusted">
```

and thank to Ruben Decrop

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<div ng-bind-html="customHtml"></div>
```

and

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngSanitize']);
```

For that, you need to include `angular-sanitize.js`,
for example in your html-file with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple (and unsafe) `bind-as-html` directive, without the need for `ngSanitize`:

```
myModule.directive('bindAsHtml', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.html(scope.$eval(attributes.bindAsHtml));
        }
    };
});
```

**Note that this will open up for security issues, if binding untrusted content.**

Use like so:

```
<div bind-as-html="someHtmlInScope"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Working example with pipe to display html in template with Angular 4.

1.Crated Pipe escape-html.pipe.ts

`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({name : 'keepHtml', pure : false})
export class EscapeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform{
 constructor(private sanitizer : DomSanitizer){
 }
 transform(content){
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
 }
}
```

`
2. Register pipe to app.module.ts

```
 import {EscapeHtmlPipe} from './components/pipes/escape-html.pipe';
    declarations: [...,EscapeHtmlPipe]
```

3. Use in your template

   ```html
       <div class="demoPipe"  [innerHtml]="getDivHtml(obj.header) | keepHtml">
   ```
4. `getDivHtml() { //can return html as per requirement}`

   Please add appropriate implementation for getDivHtml in associated component.ts file.

Comment: I think he is working with AngularJS, not the newer version.

Answer (score -2):

Just simple use `[innerHTML]`, like below:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>
```

Before you needed to use `ng-bind-html`...

Comment: This is only available within Angular (Angular version 2+), not AngularJS (Angular version 1).