# ng-bind-html does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-databinding

please look at [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vDSAH/15/) *fiddle*

please type 4 in the text area,
it should write an error message, that is in this line:

```
   $names.push('<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="snippet"></div>');
```

actually it does not. It prints the html code itself without handling,

and the underlying html is:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in list|splitList:appUsers" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
        &lt;div ng-bind-html="snippet"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    </li>
```

I tried to follow solutions from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)

but nothing seem to help,

any help in fixing it will be regarded,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got help from the chat room of angularjs,

the thing is that I should use:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="user">...</div>
```

instead of `{{user}}`

Comment: **HTML** `<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="fruitsView"></div>` with **js** `$scope.fruitsView = '<div><p>sdf</p><p>sdf<span>dfsd</span></p></div>';` is working fine. but **HTML** `<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="fruitsView"></div>` with **js** `$scope.fruitsView = '<div><p ng-repeat="each in arr">{{each}}</p></div>';` is not working.. Please have a look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/3LfU7/

Comment: One also need to inject angular-sanitize.js & to put as a dependency ngSanitize

Answer (score 7):

To get it to work you will need the following:

**Declare it in html**

```
div ng-bind-html="{expression}"></div>
```

Or

```
div class="ng-bind-html: {expression};"></div>
```

***AND***

reference `angular-sanitize.min.js` and then add

```
angular.module('YOUR_APP_NAME', ['ngSanitize']);
```

The last two are in the angularjs documentation for some reason...