# How to get the NgModelController for input fields inside a ngRepeat directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Normally, with a form and input fields, the form controller is published into the related scope under the form name attribute. And, the NgModelController is published under the input name attribute.
So for an input field with an ngModel directive, the NgModelController for the input field can be retrieved like `$scope.myFormName.myInputFieldName`

The question is how to do the same thing (get the NgModelController) for input fields inside the ngRepeat directive?

I would like to name the input fields using $index as part of the name so each template instance is uniquely named. This renders OK, so

```
<input name="foo_{{$index}}" ...
```

renders the instance with $index == 3 to

```
<input name="foo_3" ...
```

But trying to get the ngModelController via the published names does not work (it's undefined), e.g.:

```
$scope.myFormName.foo_3
```

A plunker showing this is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jYDhZfgC3Ud0fXUuP7To?p=preview

It shows successfully getting the ngModelController for a 'plain' input element and calling $setValidity, and also shows failing to get the ngModelController for an input element inside an ngRepeat directive.

Copied the relevant section of code from the plunker below:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements">
  <div ng-class="{error: form['foo_{{$index}}'].$invalid}">
    <input name="foo_{{$index}}" ng-model="element.a" type="number">
    <span ng-show="form['foo_{{$index}}'].$error.bar">ngRepeat bar invalid</span>
  </div>
</div>
{{form.foo_0.$setValidity('bar', false)}}
```

Comment: I would guess the problem is that ng-repeat creates a new scope and that you cannot simple access the child scope: similar to this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491433/accessing-the-model-inside-a-ng-repeat Sorry I don't have a nice idea how to change that other than writing a custom directive at the moment :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Flek is correct that the new child scopes that ng-repeat creates are the root of the problem here.  Since browsers do not allow nesting of <form> elements, ngForm must be used when nesting forms, or when you want to do form validation inside ngRepeat.

See [Pawel's answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/v5lK1y8-HXQ/ucq8MfcjKNsJ) on the google group thread, which shows how to use ng-form to create inner forms, and/or @blesh's [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378401/dynamic-validation-and-name-in-a-form-with-angularjs).

Comment: This answer provided the information needed to deal with the issue. The solution I came up with is to use ngForm in combination with a custom directive. As background, the goal is to render server-side validation errors; so a server submission callback would set a structure in scope. The directive would $observe the error structure. The plunkr showing this solution is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/TdihRm5iMVPb8BsUWihg

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, you are trying to have access to the form elements created inside the `ng-repeat`.

Please have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EF5Jp/. Inside the button click handler you will have the access to the element with id `myForm.foo_2`. You can notice that the element is retrieved by `myForm.foo_2` and not `$scope.myForm.foo_2`. Second thing is, changing the value using its scope and not using its value property like `angular.element(element).scope().foo = 6;`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, what I need to is access the ngModelController for the model in order to call the $setValidity method ( not the model itself ).