# How set focus on redactor editor in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have used angular-reductor editor(npm package for editor in html)
I want to focus on text-area(redector editor) on ng-click below code is not working but if i remove `redactor="redactor_options"` from text-area it works but editor don't get display.
According to angular-redector document they using jQuery method to focus but as i am working on angularjs is there any angularjs method to do this ?

In short:is there any angularjs way to focus on redector editor on ng-click ?

html file

```
`<div ng-click="focusInput=true">
<textarea ng-model="data.content" redactor="redactor_options" cols="30" rows="10" focus-me="focusInput"></textarea>
<div>'
```

Controller 
I have added directive for focus on textarea on ng-click

```
`app.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, redactor) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.focusMe, function(value) {
        if(value === true) { 
          $timeout(function() {
            element[0].focus();
            scope[attrs.focusMe] = false;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});`
```

Comment: if without `redactor="redactor_options"` works, this means that redactor is adding some html to text-area and this is probably the reason the `element[0].focus` doesn't work...I suggest you print your `element` on your directive to see what element is being passed to the function.

Comment: I checked it i am getting `textarea.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-empty
context
:
textarea.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-empty 
__proto__
:
Object(0)`

Comment: just a `string` with this information or it is an `html object`? you need to make sure you get the `html object` then you can set `focus`...print within and without `redactor="redactor_options"` to see the difference of the `element` you are getting

Comment: Its an object am getting didnt found much difference in between them (with and without redactor="redactor_options")
but without redactor in object i get dont get this `ng-untouched` but it present in with redactor

Comment: please. create a fiddlejs with your structure and I`ll try to hel[ you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwk3c65f/  is it accessiable ? sorry if there is any issue i am new here i never created fiddlejs before

Comment: as I imagined...redactor replaces your textarea...that's why it doesn't work...[see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470721/angularjs-redactor-plugin) . I think it will help you with this.