# Using angular.js 's data-binding in javascript /or updating javascript variable on event

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, angularjs

I just started using `angular.js`, and it is pretty useful. I have searched a lot maybe with wrong keywords, but I wasn't able to find how to use `angular.js`'s Data Binding in javascipt.

Here is the sample of the problem:

```
<form><select ng-model="frfiSzam" id="frfi-szam">
      <option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option> <option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option><option>14</option><option>15</option>
    </select></form>

    <div class="leir">

     <p class="fejl">{{frfiSzam}} férfi résztvevő</p>


     <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var x= '{{frfiSzam}}'
    var char = '';
    while (x--) {
        char += 'Hi!';
    }
    // write once
    document.write(char);

     </script>
```

So the thing is working ( the first part) except this one `var x= '{{frfiSzam}}'`. If I set it to a constant the code is working fine, so I think I need to update my `x` variable when the drop down value changes, but I do not know how to do it so the code works.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a watch: http://jsfiddle.net/6QG9r/

```
$scope.$watch('number', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    //this callback function gets executed whenever 'number' changes
    var x = newValue;
    $scope.hi = "";
    while (x--) {
        $scope.hi += "Hi! ";
    }
});
```

Comment: wow! thanks a lot! how can i do the same with some html elements with classes?  `$scope.hi += "<p class="sads"></p>";`

Comment: You'll have to learn to think a bit different with angular ;) i.e. DON'T write HTML with document.write() Instead, bind the information to a variable like $scope.hi and make use of it in the HTML template like <span ng-bind="hi"></span> This works also for arrays: http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/ btw, I really recommend http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/ And if my answer solved your problem, please accept it :)

Comment: there seems to be a way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs but it's not the way angular is meant to be used. put your stuff in an array and then use http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

Comment: <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="hi"></div> solved the problem!! thank you very much! :)