# How to render html with AngularJS templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my template:

```html
<div class="span12">
  <ng:view></ng:view>
</div>
```

and this is my view template:

```html
<h1>{{stuff.title}}</h1>

{{stuff.content}}
```

I am getting the `content` as html and I want to display that in a view, but all I am getting is raw html code. How can I render that HTML?

Comment: Where is the HTML coming from? Under different circumstances, you'll want `ngBindHtmlUnsafe`, `ngSanitize`, or a custom directive.

Comment: The html is coming from my database

Comment: Is the content *absolutely* trusted?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller can you please explain more about trusted. i mean i am entring the data myself but i would like to know what are the worst case scenarios

Comment: For example, if the HTML contains a `script` tag the browser would execute it. This type of "injection" attack is a common way of damaging apps and stealing user data. AngularJS has a separate module called `ngSanitize` that you can use to strip the HTML of any dangerous tags; it also has a directive called [`ngBindHtml`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive:ngBindHtml) that works just like `ngBindHtmlUnsafe`, but strips the dangerous tags for you. If the content is entirely yours - and doesn't come from users or third parties - then you don't need it.

Comment: Oh, and if you're pulling templates from a server, `ngInclude` or a (simple!) custom directive would probably be the better way to go.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert HTML into view using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 100):

Use-

```
<span ng-bind-html="myContent"></span>
```

You need to tell angular to not escape it.

Comment: It's a typo - he meant `<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="stuff.content"></span>`.

Comment: API has changed in AngularJS 1.2.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu

Comment: amccausl has saved new angular users countless hours of debugging due to angular "hell docs", ng-bind-html-unsafe is deprecated and please refer to the link located in the comment above to solve the answer.

Comment: I just inserted <span ng-bind-html="myHtmlFragment"></span> into my template and without doing anything else it worked great. I didn't have to inject $sce.  Here's the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: ngSanitize -one thing that was missing for me when using the answers here(you can get from the angular docs on ng-bind-html) is you need to make sure your app includes the ngSanitize module. Without that it did not work.

Comment: `ng-bind-html` alone worked, without using `trustAsHtml`

Comment: @MarcoLackovic this function makes sure to avoid html exploits see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Answer (score 50):

To do this, I use a custom filter.

In my app:

```
myApp.filter('rawHtml', ['$sce', function($sce){
  return function(val) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
  };
}]);
```

Then, in the view:

```
<h1>{{ stuff.title}}</h1>

<div ng-bind-html="stuff.content | rawHtml"></div>
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution @Daniel. If I am using the `$sce.trustAsHtml`, I dont need to include the `ngSanitize` dependency to the app module? I am using Angular 1.3

Comment: Can we use ng-include to achieve this?

Comment: this does not work for me, i am using angular 7. Kindly suggest the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In angular 4+ we can use `innerHTML` property instead of `ng-bind-html`.

In my case, it's working and I am using **angular 5**.

```
<div class="chart-body" [innerHTML]="htmlContent"></div>
```

In.ts file

```
let htmlContent = 'This is the `<b>Bold</b>` text.';
```

Answer (score 3):

You shoud follow the Angular docs and use $sce - $sce is a service that provides Strict Contextual Escaping services to AngularJS. Here is a docs: http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe

Let's take an example with asynchroniously loading Eventbrite login button

In your controller:

```
someAppControllers.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', 'eventbriteLogin', 
  function($scope, $sce, eventbriteLogin) {

    eventbriteLogin.fetchButton(function(data){
      $scope.buttonLogin = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
    });
  }]);
```

In your view just add:

```
<span ng-bind-html="buttonLogin"></span>
```

In your services:

```
someAppServices.factory('eventbriteLogin', function($resource){
   return {
        fetchButton: function(callback){
            Eventbrite.prototype.widget.login({'app_key': 'YOUR_API_KEY'}, function(widget_html){
                callback(widget_html);
            })
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So maybe you want to have this in your index.html to load the library, script, and initialize the app with a view:

```
<html>
  <body ng-app="yourApp">
    <div class="span12">
      <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then yourView.html could just be:

```
<div>
  <h1>{{ stuff.h1 }}</h1>
  <p>{{ stuff.content }}</p>
</div>
```

scripts.js could have your controller with data $scope'd to it.

```
angular.module('yourApp')
    .controller('YourCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.stuff = {
        'h1':'Title',
        'content':"A paragraph..."
      };
    });
```

Lastly, you'll have to config routes and assign the controller to view for it's $scope (i.e. your data object)

```
angular.module('yourApp', [])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/yourView.html',
      controller: 'YourCtrl'
    });
});
```

I haven't tested this, sorry if there's a bug but I think this is the Angularish way to get data

Comment: What if I want this same behavior but not depend on routeProvider?

Comment: It's the same using ui-router, only it's $stateProvider instead of $routeProvider and 
.state( 'yourState', {
  url:'/', 
  templateUrl: 'yourView.html',
  controller: 'YourCtrl'
 });