# Display raw HTML markup from CKEditor in Angular template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I use CKEditor in my AngularJS Application. When I try to display the text that I saved from the `TextEditor`, it doesn't take the style. For Example if I want to display a sentence it appears as:

```
<p>How old are you</p>
```

instead of :

> How old are you

I tried using `ng-bind`:

```
<div ng-bind="Item.Header"></div>
```

and the regular binding method:

```
<h3>{{Item.Header}}</h3>
```

But both methods didn't work. Is there a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "[ngBindHtmlUnsafe](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe)". Since this command doesn't sanitize the expression, but you should only use it if you trust the source.

So the html will be written as follows:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="Item.Header"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754515/how-to-render-html-with-angular-templates

Comment: ng-bind-html-unsafe removed in 1.2 rc1