# AngularJS - data binding that accepts html tags in input form to convert <b> to an html element

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is the general idea of what I am trying to accomplish:

The user has an input box. When the user enters text and hits enter the input is sent to a function that inserts it into an array which displays it in an ng-repeat. The actual input is from the array is data binded in a span element like so:

```
        <span style="text-overflow:ellipsis;">
            {{choice.text}}
        </span>
```

What I want to do is for the user to enter < b>My text< /b> and then it will be interpreted as html element < b> < /b>inside the span element with text in the middle like so:

```
        <span style="text-overflow:ellipsis;">
            <b >My text </b>
        </span>
```

However, it displays it only as text rather than an actual element. Any idea how I can implement that?

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754515/how-to-render-html-with-angular-templates ?

Comment: can you give own ng-repeat html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attribute `ng-bind-html-unsafe`

```
<b ng-bind-html-unsafe>test</b>
```