# How to parse html tags inside string in angular js

Tags: angularjs

in controller i have a variable say $scope.question.

```
$scope.question = "Hi this is <br/> book";
```

In html page is access this variable like {{question}}.

```
<div class="question">
        1. {{question}}
</div>
```

i want the output with line break... But instead it display as string... how to parse the html tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render html with angular templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754515/how-to-render-html-with-angular-templates)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `ng-bind-html` directive. To utilise that you need to:

```
//1. given
.controller('AppController', [
  function() {
   $scope.SomeHtml = '<b>some html</b>';


//2. use ng-bind
 <div ng-bind-html="SomeHtml"></div>
```

Check the demo [from official AngularJS documentation on plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdXGkDUTheUK3mdLAW4r?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

If our text contains some html content, then we have to use ng-bind-html directive in angular js, else our html content will not be parsed and will be rendered as it is.

Example:

If our text is

```
  $scope.Val = "<span> Something </span>"
```

and we write this text within curly brackets as follows:

```
  <div> {{Val}}  </div>
```

then the text will be rendered as it is i.e.    Something

Therefore in order to get this html content parsed we have to write it as follows:

```
  <div ng-bind-html="Val"></div>
```

Now the text will be rendered as Something .

Note: Make sure to include ngSanitize module on your app eg:

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Hope it helps...!