# Is it possible to read in HTML tags within a JSON object, and display them on a webpage?

Tags: html, json, angular, angular2-http

I have a JSON object that looks like the following:

```
id:
text: <h1>This is my text</h1> <p> I want to include HTML 
            and reflect those tags on the page. </p>
```

I'm using Angular2's HTTP_PROVIDER to read the data from the JSON.

In my HTML template, I am displaying the JSON.dataString on the webpage.  How do I reflect the HTML tags on the webpage, currently the tags are displayed as plain text.

```
<p>{{jsonObject.text}}</p>
```

Is there a way to read in those HTML tags that are included in the JSON objects, and have them reflected on the webpage?

Comment: Maybe that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754515/how-to-render-html-with-angular-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
<div [innerHTML]="jsonObject.text"></div>
```

Should display the text object as raw HTML. Be careful about XSS injection when you do something like this.

More detail at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding).

Comment: Thank you! This worked without the square brackets.. <div innerHTML="{{jsonObject.text}}"></div>

Comment: I believe it originally supposed to be `<div [innerHTML]="jsonObject.text"></div>"`. And no, there's no need to worry about XSS, Angular handles this.

Comment: @estus By using innerHTML, you are bypassing Angular's encoding of HTML, which means you are bypassing it's XSS protection.

Comment: That's not true. The result of innerHTML binding is unescaped, sanitized markup. Harmful things (including anything script-related) can't be added this way to the document. And if you find that they can, feel free to open an issue. See [more on the subject](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#xss).

Answer (score 1):

You may try to do it like this:

```
function textHtml(input) {
    var el = document.createElement("textarea");
    el.innerHTML = input;
    return el.value;
}
```

And then use this function to get text with tags

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Angular but do something like that.

```
<p id="myId"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("myId").appendChild(jsonObject.text);
</script>
```

I did not test it.