# AngularJS Convert Text to HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Okay so I am learning AngularJS, and one functionality is to allow the user to type HTML code into a textarea, this gets sent to the Controller and stored in a code variable. When the user presses the button to test the code, I want the text to be inserted into the HTML document. Currently all it does is add it as plain text, so not rendering it.

test-code.template.js:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.showCode()">Test Code</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.clearCode()">Reset All</button>

{{$ctrl.codeShow}}
```

test-code.component.js:

```
angular.
  module('phonecatApp').
  component('testCode', {
    templateUrl: 'Components/test-code/test-code.template.html',
    controller: [function TestCodeController() {
      var self = this;

  self.code = '';
  self.codeShow = '';

  self.showCode = function showCode()
  {
    self.codeShow = self.code;
  }

  self.clearCode = function clearCode()
  {
    self.codeShow = '';
    self.code = '';
  }

  }]
  });
```

Just to clarify, pressing the buttons do work and the data is successfully added from code to codeShow on the button press, and it can display it, but it is displayed as clear text instead of rendering. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render html with AngularJS templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754515/how-to-render-html-with-angularjs-templates)

Comment: Sidenote, in 2025 I will still be amazed by the number of people starting to learn AngularJS (Angular 1), when Angular 2 was released in September 2016 and the current version is 7

Comment: @JeremyThille come on. it is not wrong to start somewhere.

Comment: I started working for a company that still has a few projects that are run in AngularJS for some odd reason.

Comment: @holydragon But why start learning an outdated framework? It's like learning Prototype instead of jQuery

Comment: @GoodDisplayName aaah I get it, this is a good reason :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 <div ng-bind-html="$ctrl.codeShow"></div>
```

also, do refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize for better implementation

Comment: Would ngSanitize help? Using that render code like h1 tags, but, for example a button tag gets rendered as only displaying the name of the button