# AngularJS - Render HTML tags that are contained in a string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, escaping

My database stores product information, and a lot of this is organised into lists. I load the data into Angular as `$scope.post`.

For instance,

```
$scope.post.size_description = '<li> Fits true to size. Take your normal size\r</li>
   <li> Slim-cut, mid-rise style</li>
   <li> Long in length, alter to fit</li>
   <li> Model wears an IT 48\r</li>
   <li> Model measures: waist size 32, height 6\'1"/ 185cm\r</li>'.
```

When I try to load this data into my Angular app, it gets rendered as text (i.e. the `<li>` are not parsed). I understand this probably happens for security reasons, but is there any way around it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert HTML into view using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)

Comment: Have a look: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile

Comment: I've found a more complete answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Damax has said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11640420/769083

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="post.size_description"></div>
```

Comment: ng-bind-html-unsafe has been depreciated since Angular 1.2. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Answer (score 8):

ngBindHtml worked for me. See more in the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.size_description"></div>
```