# Render subscript to HTML from js object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on an Angular 1X application which has stored all icon labels into a js object like this

```
var labels={
  ........
  iconlabel_o2:"O<sub>2</sub>",
  iconLabel_co2:"CO<sub>2</sub>",
  iconLabel_h20:"H<sub>2</sub>O",
  ........
}
```

and the iconLabel values are called into HTML

```
<p>{{u.iconLabel}}</p>
```

but the values are not getting rendered as subscripts. It just shows the whole string. like this...

```
O<sub>2</sub>
CO<sub>2</sub>
H<sub>2</sub>O
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `iconlabel.o2` et al are **not** valid object literal keys

Comment: sorry about that.. i corrected those..thanks for pointing out

Comment: Also, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ng-bind-html` directive to achieve this:

```
<p ng-bind-html="u.iconLabel"></p>
```

Please also have a look at a similar question: [AngularJS - Render HTML tags that are contained in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826758/angularjs-render-html-tags-that-are-contained-in-a-string)