# How to pass rendering angular js html string to html page

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I want to pass the angularjs rendering data to html file. I'm passing but the hole HTML tags and all showing in front end

This is my js file code:

```
var html = "";
    html += '<h4 class="c-white">[\''+dkey+'\']</h4>';
    $scope.oc.dayHtml[rmoment.format('YYYY-MM-DD')] = html;
```

This is my HTML file code:

```
<div class="listview lv-bordered lv-lg m-b-15">
                            {{::oc.dayHtml[day]}}
                        </div>
```

**Note :** See Here I'm passing Date but it is showing with HTML tag. Also, i don't want html tages only i want date only.

See output Front end like this coming:

```
<h4 class="c-white">['2019-12-30']</h4>
<h4 class="c-white">['2019-12-31']</h4>
```

Comment: Check this page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826758/angularjs-render-html-tags-that-are-contained-in-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Issue

I believe the issue you're running into here is something called "Strict Contextual Escaping". Basically, to prevent Evil Horrible People™ from running malicious code on your site thru stuff like the following:

```
<div id='my-div'>
 <!--Also please don't use IDs that are stupid as this one, kthx-->
 <input id='html-inp' ng-model='someInput'>
 <div class='result'>{{someInput}}</div>
 OR...
 <div class='result' ng-bind-html='someInput'></div>
</div>
```

If you ran this code inside a normal, otherwise-perfectly-functional AngularJS app, you could put whatever you want in `#html-inp`, and assume that it'd show up in both of those `.result` divs. *However*... If you type any HTML in there - for example, "`<i>This text is supposed to be italic!</i>`", it'll show the exact the code you've typed in, not the "rendered" version that you want it to.

#### `ng-bind-html-unsafe`

To avoid this, one way *used* to be using the `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive, as the linked question above suggests. However, that's been removed, so depending on what sub-version of AngularJS you're using, that's not likely to work.

#### `$sce`

Instead, you now need to use the Strict Contextual Escaping module (someone else please correct this if it's not actually called a "module". Is it a service?), `$sce`:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myAwesomeApp',[]).controller('myController',function($scope,$sce,someOtherModule){
  ...the rest of your code.
```

That will allow you to do stuff like this:

```
//we're inside an angularjs controller here
$scope.someRenderedHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.someVarWithRawHtml);
```

If you wanna use this in your HTML, you could do it like:

```
<div class='result' ng-bind-html='someRenderedHTML'></div>
```

Alternatively, you could create a filter:

```
.filter('trustMe', ['$sce', function($sce){
   return function(text) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
   }
}])
```

And just do `<div class='result' ng-bind-html='someVarWithRawHtml|trustMe'></div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-bind-html="oc.dayHtml[day]" />
```

Comment: Hi seunggabi, thanks for your replaying i applied ng-bind-html-unsafe="oc.dayHtml[day]" but same HTML tages also coming.

Comment: See my screen output like this : <h4 class="c-white">['2019-12-30']</h4>
<h4 class="c-white">['2019-12-31']</h4

Comment: No same HTML tag only coming see this: <h4 class="c-white">['2019-12-30']</h4> ,,,i want only for date like this :2019-12-30

Comment: @Jay I don't know not working reason. check code this https://plnkr.co/edit/5rOzmXZ1JGyCEpZqL8Bg?p=preview

Comment: Review: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).
I mark your answer for deletion until update.

Comment: no it's not correct i need only for data like : 02-08-2019

Comment: @seunggabi Please add text explaining how this will work

Comment: It won't work. The issue you're running into is SCE.