# Angularjs use custom interpolation symbols for scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, angularjs-directive

I currently have an underscore.js template that I would also like to use with angular and still be able to use with underscore.  I was wondering if it's possible to change the interpolation start and end symbols for a particular scope using a directive, like this:

```
angular.directive('underscoreTemplate', function ($parse, $compile, $interpolateProvider, $interpolate) {
     return {
         restrict: "E",
         replace: false,
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
             $interpolateProvider.startSymbol("<%=").endSymbol("%>");
             var parsedExp = $interpolate(element.html());
             // Then replace element contents with interpolated contents
         }
     }
 })
```

But this spits out the error

> Error: Unknown provider: $interpolateProviderProvider <- $interpolateProvider <- underscoreTemplateDirective

Is `$interpolateProvider` only available for module configuration?  Would a better solution be to simply using string replace to change `<%=` to `{{` and `%>` to `}}`?

Also, I noticed that `element.html()` escapes the `<` in `<%=` and `>` in `%>`.  Is there a way to prevent this automatic escaping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, you have a couple issues here, but **I found a solution for you**.

## Demo

**http://jsfiddle.net/colllin/zxwf2/**

## Issue 1

Your `<` and `>` characters are being converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;`, so when you call `element.html()`, you won't even find an instance of `<` or `>` in that string.

## Issue 2

Since the `$interpolate` service has already been "provided" by the `$interpolateProvider`, it doesn't look like you can edit the startSymbol and endSymbol.  **However**, you can convert your custom startSymbol and endSymbol to the angular start/end symbols dynamically in your linking function.

## Solution

```
myApp.directive('underscoreTemplate', function ($parse, $compile, $interpolate) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var startSym = $interpolate.startSymbol();
            var endSym = $interpolate.endSymbol();
            var rawExp = element.html();
            var transformedExp = rawExp.replace(/&lt;%=/g, startSym).replace(/&lt;%-/g, startSym).replace(/%&gt;/g, endSym);
            var parsedExp = $interpolate(transformedExp);

            scope.$watch(parsedExp, function(newValue) {
                element.html(newValue);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

## Alternatives

I'm not sure how, but I'm sure there's a way to instantiate your own custom `$interpolate` service using the `$interpolateProvider` (after configuring it for underscore tags).

Comment: Thanks, this works great! I made one small change (use regex with 'g') to replace all instances: http://jsfiddle.net/e3s5d/

Comment: Great call.  Updated answer.

Comment: Now that you point out the `<%-` syntax, I'm realizing that the default `<%=` in underscore is more analogous to angular's `<div ng-bind-html="myHtml"></div>`. Maybe you could add some logic to this directive to allow unescaped html by replacing `'<%='` in the raw expression with `'<div ng-bind-html="'` and then the following `'%>'` with `'"></div>'`. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10971756/361609