# Ng-bind-html with AngularJS filter and Angular-ui highlight

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to use an AngularJS filter to search for a piece of text in a table and then use [Angular-ui highlight](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/) to highlight the text.

I have the following code:

Search field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText"/>
```

Table with `ng-repeat` and angular-ui `highlight`

```
<table ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
    <tr>
        <td>{{ fruit.name | highlight:searchText }}</td>
        <td>{{ fruit.price }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But my result looks like this:

[image: Resulting HTML]

I think I should be using `ng-bind-html-unsafe`, but am not sure of the correct way to implement it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="fruit.name | highlight:searchText"></span>
```

Comment: I tried that earlier (and included the angular sanitize module), but will try again.

Comment: @AndrewBoni If you use `ng-bind-html`, you need `sanitize` module, but if you the `unsafe` one you don't need that. (the `unsafe` one is not available in 1.2)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue, with help from user sza.

I am using AngularJS 1.2, and need to be using `ng-bind-html` not `ng-bind-html-unsafe`. The next step was to include the `angular-sanitize.js` script. The last step was to include in the directive `ngSanitize` to `app.js`.

[Source and additional reading here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)

Comment: Thaaaanks!!!!!! This was it: "The last step was to include in the directive ngSanitize to app.js"