# Dynamic angularjs template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive this way -

```
scope.nodeTemplate = '{{node.nodeText}}';
```

**Part of template**

```
'<ul>' +
    '<li class="tree-node" data-ng-repeat="node in nodes">' +
        '<span>' + scope.nodeTemplate + '</span>' +
    '</li>' +
'</ul>'
```

Based on some condition I would like to change the `nodeTemplate` and it can be an html string like -

```
'<input type="text"/>'
```

But the issue is when it try to do this thing `angular` does not render the html. It simply puts the html string. I am kind of stuck here. Can someone suggest some solution?

Comment: this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ng-bind-html-unsafe like:

```
'<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="nodeTemplate"></span>'
```