# Enter Character should print a new line in html

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I am getting `"First Line.↵Second Line↵"` as a string in an api response.I want to take this and print in html web page like `<span>{{apiText}}</span>`. where apiText is a javascript variable whose value is `"First Line.↵Second Line↵"`. But the text appears on one line only.How to I convert `↵` to a format where it prints a break.

Comment: may be you should share your js code...

Comment: i am using ember so 
in the controller i get the text and store in apiText = "First Line.↵Second Line↵"
and then in html i just refer apiText in span

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473021/insert-html-into-view-using-emberjs

Comment: Use `{{{` with extremely with cautious, that might lead to security risk. refer https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_escaping-html-content

Comment: You *could* wrap it in a `<pre>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cr character is `\n`.

You can replace those with `<br>` tag.

```
refinedText: Ember.computed('apiText', function(){
  return this.get('apiText').replace('\n', '<br>');
})
```

and in template :

```
{{{refinedText}}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are appending the variable to the `span` . Append it as `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`

If you are using `Ember.js` try  using 3 curly braces: `<span>{{{apiText}}}</span>`