# Rendering json data (having anchor tag) to html page

Tags: json, html, angularjs

I have json data having anchor tag .

task.json

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Launch an EC2 Instance",
        "desc": "Needed an <a href='#'>EC2</a> instance to deploy the ccr code",
        "status": "done",
        "percentage_finished": 100
    }]
}
```

I am using angularjs to render this data to my html page . But anchor tag is not working.
It prints as it is as Text.

```
<div class="task-pn panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-heading"><b>Description : Task-{{task_detail.id}}</b></div>
     <div class="panel-body"> 
         <div onclick="this.contentEditable='true';">{{task_detail.desc}}</div>  
     </div>
</div>
```

Output img.

[image]

I need a simple link to EC2 word .How to deal with this isuue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Comment: Thanks!! above link helps me. Now its working using ngSanitize module and ng-bind-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[user2720708](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2720708/user2720708) :Thanks for sharing your ideas.

[eRIZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2324004/eriz) gave this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs) .There I used the idea of [Luke Madera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429106/luke-madera).

Current working html page .

```
<div class="task-pn panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading"><b>Description : Task-{{task_detail.id}}</b></div>
   <div class="panel-body"> 
      <div contentEditable" ng-bind-html="task_detail.desc"></div>  
   </div>
</div>
```

and Then I follow only two steps :

> 1.include the angular-sanitize.min.js resource, i.e.:
>
> 2.In a js file (controller or usually app.js), include ngSanitize, i.e.:
>   angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services',
>   'myApp.directives', 'ngSanitize']) ---------from answer given by [Luke Madera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429106/luke-madera)

Its working now ...:)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

In your controller:

```
scope.trustedHtml = sce.trustAsHtml(json.desc);
```

And to use it in your partial:

```
<p class="org-desc" ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"> </p>
```