# Angular JS shows HTML within the tag

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I am trying to insert HTML inside template using `ng-bind-html-unsafe` attribute. But for some reason its not working.

My code:

```
<tr class="white two-button" ng-repeat="(key,value) in recommendations | ojoScoreFilter:ojoScore | relevancyScoreFilter:relevancyScore | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
<td>
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="value.button"></div>
</td>
</tr>
```

I am not able to see the HTML.
If I change `ng-bind-html-unsafe="value.button"` to `ng-bind-html-unsafe="{{value.button}}"` then it shows HTML but within the attribute, something like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="&lt;a class=&quot;action_hrefs full-width bgcolor10 purple-hover flat-button flat-white-button btn&quot; data-value=&quot;947&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-lock&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&nbsp;Unlock&lt;/a&gt;"></div>
```

Comment: Try to include 'ngSanitize' module in your module and ng-bind-html in your mark up

Comment: what version of angular are you using?  `ng-bind-html-unsafe` was removed in Angular version 1.2.

Comment: @DavinTryon I am using 1.2.9

Comment: Check out [ng-bind-html](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) then.  You need to use this directive in conjunction with `$sce` service.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Ok I found solution for this:

JS:

```
$scope.renderHtml = function(html_code)
{
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
};
```

HTML:

```
<p ng-bind-html="renderHtml(value.button)"></p>
```

Comment: Woah this is the only one that worked! I've tried everything, thank you :)

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me as well. Be sure to inject $sce into your controller.

Comment: This works, but seems a bit overkill. I have to inject $sce into every controller? And have to add that `renderHtml` function to every controller that needs html?

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me too. The accepted answer found in this other SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs did NOT work.

Comment: In order for this to work, make sure to inject $sce into the function defined in the controller, something like this: `myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {`

Comment: This really worked for me and to help @AndrewGee, instead to add the $sce on all controllers, you just make it available on your main controler like $scope.$sce = $sce ... doing this, you can just call $scope.$sce anywhere you want, because, this is already available and exposed on your scope.

Comment: Another smart thing to do... is to add $scope.renderHtml on your main scope with $id 002... and just call this function any time you need

Comment: @Griiettner can you elaborate on that?

Comment: It's already been mentioned the $sce service needs to be invoked by the controller, i.e.: `myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) { /* ... */  }]);` but, to be clear: you also need to include the `ngSanitize` module in your javascript on the page and in your app declaration: `myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize','myCtrl']);`

Answer (score 14):

make a filter like this

```
.filter('trusted',
   function($sce) {
     return function(ss) {
       return $sce.trustAsHtml(ss)
     };
   }
)
```

and apply this as a filter to the ng-bind-html like

```
<div ng-bind-html="code | trusted">
```

Comment: The accepted answer above got a lot of votes but I think this solution is a better answer. Doing it this way will solve the issue of having to inject $sce into every controller that will display html. I'm still new at this though, so feel free to correct me!