# How to use Solr Highlight tag in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, solr

All:

Right now, what I want to do is very basic:

Just use the default highlight feature of Solr, and show the result on page.

But strange thing is : I get the highlight string which like "asds < em>keyword</em>", but it was treated as a pure string, in the html: it is wrap in "", I wonder how can I make that  treated as tag?

Thanks

**UPDATE This update is replaced by UPDATE2**

I have figured out myself in a dangerous unsuggested way:

```
    app.config(function($sceProvider) {
              // Completely disable SCE.  For demonstration purposes only!
              // Do not use in new projects.
              $sceProvider.enabled(false);
            });

//In this way, we can disable that so-called **sanitize**
```

**UPDATE2** Thanks to MatsLindh

Refer to [Angular JS shows HTML within the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829275/angular-js-shows-html-within-the-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to disable sanitize completely. Just [tell Angular that HTML is OK for that single expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs).

This is currently done with:

```
<div ng-bind-html="expression"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I use the same ng-bind-html in my page, but AngularJS gives me a error which says: "Error: error:unsafe
Require a safe/trusted value
Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context."

Comment: You'll need to wrap it to tell AngularJS that the value is safe - see the comments in the linked post above, or [AngluarJS HTML within a Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829275/angular-js-shows-html-within-the-tag)

Comment: So the diff between $sce.trustAsHtml and $sce.enable(false) is one is limit that locally while the other  make it global disabled?