# Display HTML in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a angular coding what need insert html tags, I found out I can use  `ngSanitize` :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize , but I don't whant load another library in that project.

I tried this: [AngularJS : Render HTML in $scope variable in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547936/angularjs-render-html-in-scope-variable-in-view)

but I could not make work.

It's any way to do this without load another angular library?

**html:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul class="procedures">
    <li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures">
      <h4><a href="#" ng-click="show = !show">{{procedure.icon}}</a></h4>
      <div class="procedure-details" ng-show="show">
        <p>text here: {{procedure.text}}</p>
        <p>your number is: {{procedure.number}}</p>
        <p>price you will pay: {{procedure.price}}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.procedures = [{
    icon: '<i class="fa fa-american-sign-language-interpreting" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
    text: 'test text',
    number: 1,
    price: 10000
  }];


}
```

**jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/wD7gR/247/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from version `1.2.0`, angular contains [$sce service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce), that can be used to mark html as "safe"

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wD7gR/249/)

```js
angular
.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.procedures = [
        {
            icon: $sce.trustAsHtml('<i class="fa fa-american-sign-language-interpreting" aria-hidden="true">i am icon</i>'),
            text: 'test text',
            number: 1,
            price: 10000
        }
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul class="procedures">
        <li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures">
            <h4><a href="#" ng-click="show = !show" ng-bind-html="procedure.icon"></a></h4>
             <div class="procedure-details" ng-show="show">
                <p>text here: {{procedure.text}}</p>
                <p>your number is: {{procedure.number}}</p>
                <p>price you will pay: {{procedure.price}}</p>
             </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it is what I want  but your code is broken now display the div before I click in the icon.

Comment: @Raduken a removed all the code, that is not related to the topic. I'm sure, you'll be able to add any logic for hide/show without a trouble ;-)

Comment: @Raduken, anyway, I updated embedded code snippet with show/hide on click.

Comment: @Raduken I'm really glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ngSanitize you can use `$sce` az filter like this:

Put this code in app.js :

```
app.filter('sce', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml;
}]);
```

Then use in Html like this:

```
<h4><a href="#" ng-click="show = !show" ng-bind-html="procedure.icon | sce"></a></h4>
```

Comment: thanks a lot but can you should me into my code? will be possible? thank you.

Comment: @Raduken Sorry, don't get what you mean?

Comment: how can apply what you said into this code? http://jsfiddle.net/wD7gR/247/

Comment: @Raduken wait a moment

Answer (score 0):

I can tell u that u can do  like below It should be as following

```
$scope.html = "<i class='fa fa-american-sign-language-interpreting' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
```

and

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="html"></div>
```

You can do the same for for icon, text or whatever u like... I'm not sure how to do that right now cuz I'm typing this from mobile fone, i hope u will get the idea, if not plz leave comment and i'll write a full function once i get my hands on machine.

Comment: thanks, but can you should me how can apply this into my real code? I could not make work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular-sanitize to insert HTML in a view.

[Example is given in plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/C1Xly1dmOwMPaap00umX?p=preview)

```
app.filter("trust", ['$sce', function($sce) {return function(htmlCode){
return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode); }}]);
```