# AngularJS displaying Google ads as code

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have Google ads Javascript code in database. I am fetching the data as `JSON` type. When I am displaying these ads in my partial page, it's displaying just code - not the actual ad.

I tried to add a directive with `$compile(element)(scope)` and `$sce.trustAsJs(element)`, but no luck.

E.g. <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                
                
                <script>
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                </script>
This code is in my DB as ads.

And I am displaying like this {{ google_ads }}.

I also tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert HTML into view using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)

Comment: can you show some examples?

Comment: am asuming you have it enclused in script tags?