# How to refresh the templateUrl in an opened modal from Angular-ui Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I have a modal that using a `templateUrl`. I would like the refresh the html in the template. How can I do that without closing the modal?

I have a modal using a view shared in different context. And depending of the route, actions happens in this view. I change my routes and my modal still open but it's template won't refresh because I don't want the view that contains the modal to reload.

Can I switch the template while the modal is open?

I would like to reload the  `assets/templates/myTemplate.html` while the modal is open:

```
$modal.open({
  templateUrl: "assets/templates/myTemplate.html",
  controller: "controller",
  scope: $scope
});
```

Comment: can you explain more better what you want to do by asking refresh template, or show your code/ share your idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the content in the modal, using ng-bind-html

```
   <div ng-bind-html="myContent"></div>
```

It also requires to sanitize the content including ngSanitize module

```
   angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize']);
```

Then you can change the content, modifying the variable $scope.myContent.

Here is the Plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZiUOoEFEoSgN4fOgKCh5?p=preview

I hope it helps

Reference: [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)