# HTML text into $scope property in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**controller**

```
    define(['angular', 'services','text',
'text!ang/templates/dinamic.html'], function (angular,s,t,template) {
    var _temp = template;


        return angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.services'])

            .controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'version', function ($scope, version) {
                $scope.scopedAppVersion =  template ;  
            }])
    })
```

template is HTML text : 
**dinamic.html**

```
 <p><b> Dinamic Url Text template</b></p>
```

index.html :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">{{scopedAppVersion}}</div>
```

In browser i see `<p><b> Dinamic Url Text template</b></p>` .He don't parse HTML - tags .
How to fix ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Comment: Angular has its own template system built in so you probably want to use that instead?

Comment: BelgianMyWaffle :  I did not fit the proposed answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can use following solution

**view**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
```

**app**

```
app.constant('templateUrl', '1.html')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, templateUrl, $sce) {
    $scope.templateUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(templateUrl);
  });
```

demo http://plnkr.co/edit/Nr9FwN?p=preview