# Insert HTML code AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I'm trying to insert this html code with a variable ***$scope.text***:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div data-drop="true" ng-model='list1' 
         data-jqyoui-options="optionsList1" jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">
      <div ng-repeat="item in list1" ng-show="item.title" 
           data-drag="{{item.drag}}" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" 
           ng-model="list1" jqyoui-draggable=\"{index: {{$index}},animate:true}\">
           {{item.title}}</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In html file of Angularjs I use: *`<div ng-bind-html="text"></div>`*

And the problem is, that in my Web Inspector only have:

```
<ul><li>
     <div >{{item.title}}</div>
</li></ul>
```

How can i show all parameters?

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in the console ?

Comment: Nop.. and the $scope.text have the correct html code..

Comment: I think this is the way how defaul $sanitize service work. It just removes potentially unsave stuff from your HTML. Check for details and examples: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert HTML into view using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is $sanitize:

HTML file:

```
<div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div>
```

Controller file:

```
$scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.texto);
};
```

Installing Sanitize:

> npm install angular-sanitize

Comment: If you include `ngSanitize` module, you don't need the `$sce.trustAsHtml()` in the controller as well.  `ngSanitize` will do this by default.