# dynamic HTML rendering in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a model in angular view. I am passing String to the model from the controller as

```
<b>myName</b>
```

hoping it to be displayed in bold, but I am not getting the desired result. Instead its getting displayed as a string as it is. Why is it so,and what is the fix? I thought angular directive compile would help, but no help.

Comment: Make sure you are using [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert HTML into view using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)

Comment: if you are in the html page, have you forget the {{ }} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing string to models in scope directly, you should use [sce.trustAsHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml)

```
$scope.bindHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml("<b>myName</b>");
```

Then in your view template, use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) to handle html binding.

```
<div ng-bind-html="bindHTML"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to see your code it's hard to say exactly what's going on but my guess is you probably need to the model using [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml). If your model has an html string in it then that's usually the way to go.