# How do I return HTML to shown as HTML and not as text when using $http Angular

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I've been stuck on this for days.

Basically I have a $http.post with Angular, posting an e-mail address and message to be emailed from post.php. Post.php is then echoing text depending on the result of the mail(), but when I return

Success

for example, it will actually show the HTML on the DOM instead of process it.

Appreciate any help.

```
app.controller('contactsController', function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {

        $rootScope.currentPage = "contact";
        $scope.postData = {};
        $scope.data = "Send";

        $scope.runScript = function() {
            $http({
                url: "post.php",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: $.param({"postData":$scope.postData})
            }).success(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                console.log(data);
                $scope.contactForm.$valid = false;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.status = status;
            });

        };
    });
<?php

// get the raw POST data

$inputData = $_POST['postData'];

if(isset($inputData["email"])&&isset($inputData["message"])) {

    $email = $inputData["email"];
    $message = $inputData["message"];

    $to = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXXX.COM"; // required

    $from = $email; // required

    $body = $message;

    $subject = "Online Query Submission";


// create email headers

    if(mail($to,$subject,$body,"From:$from/r/nReply-to:$from"))
        echo "<p>Success - Thanks!</p>";
    else
        echo "<p>Error - Sorry!</p>";

}

 ?>
```

Comment: Personally I would have just returned text from the server without the HTML so that way, if I wanted to change the presentation later, I wouldn't have to worry about the server or data, it would just be the markup itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should use `ng-bind-html` in your view, like so:

```
<div ng-bind-html="data"></div>
```

as you attribute the message returned from the server to a controller $scope variable, like so:

```
$http(url).success(function(data){
$scope.data=data;
});
```

From [angularjs doc about ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml),

> `ng-bind-html` evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way

Comment: Anybody else struggling with this, don't forget to check Docs regarding ng-bind-html. It requires ngSanitize as dependency. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly find what you want here [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)

However, I think it will be a good practice to make PHP return just a confirmation text and formate it on the front end using Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Although everybody has helped fantastically, `ng-bind-html="data"` was part of the problem.

The remaining problem was that I didn't realise `ngSanitize` was a requirement, get it in as a dependency and it works perfect :)

I believe there is a quicker way to bypass ngSanitize, something like `$sce.trustAsHtml`, but not considered a good practice I believe.

Comment: you mean you had used it in your html, and had not mentioned it?

Comment: As I was investigating your helpful answer in Docs, I realised it needs ngSanitize - I had tried it before although thought I probably didn't use it correctly. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: and thank you for the $sce.trustAsHtml trick, good to know :) Maybe not as safe as ng-bind-html, but with a <p>message</p>, there is not much of a risk anyway