# Displaying HTML in an Angular 1.3.9 view with $sce

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to display an HTML string in my Angular view.

At first, I naively tried this :

```
<p>{{ad.text}}</p>

$scope.ad = { 'text' : '<a href="#">Link</a>'}; // Dynamically fetched, etc. This is just an example text
```

But this just displays `<a href="#">Link</a>` in the view, not : [link](http://#).

After some research, I stumbled upon ngSanitize. I tried it, but it totally strips off all HTML code to leave just raw text. Pretty secure indeed. A bit too much, actually. Anyway, **ngSanitize is now outdated**.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs) indicates that now the $sce service has to be used instead of ngSnitize.

Following these various solutions, here is what I came up with :

HTML

```
<p ng-bind-html="htmlAdText"></p>
```

JS

```
$scope.ad = { 'text' : '<a href="#">Link</a>'};

$scope.htmlAdText = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.ad.text);
```

But this error comes in the console :

```
ReferenceError: $sce is not defined
```

What bugs me is that **the $sce service is supposed to be part of Angular's core since v1.2, and I'm using v1.3.9**.

What's going on here?
Does anyone have a definitive method to display HTML in an AngularJS view ( without filters that just leave the raw text) ?

Comment: Try using angular.element

Comment: What do you mean? Inject HTML using a jQuery wrapper? How would you do that on `ad.text` change? I'm having a look at it.

Comment: Did you inject $sce into your controller?

Comment: I'm using it normally on 1.3.x. Can you provide more code, like how your controller look like?

Comment: That was it. It's part of the core, but it also needs to be injected it in the controller. Thanks guys

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Don't forget to inject it into controller, for instance:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', [ '$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce){
    $scope.ad = { 'text' : '<a href="#">Link</a>'};
    $scope.htmlAdText = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.ad.text);
}]); //End Controller
```

Comment: Damn it, was it that simple? So it's part of the core, but you also have to inject it? I'm not used to Angular enough yet. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you have to manually inject it into the controller, which when you think about it, makes sense. Otherwise you would otherwise constantly be injecting all services into your controller, even those you don't use. This would just be bloating the controller for no reason other than not having to write it out explicitly, and being explicit and not bloating is preferable to being implicit and bloating in this case.

Comment: This example just saved my ass: thank you Samir Alajmovic! In my code the syntax was slightly different like: .controller('DingleheimersController', function ($scope, $sce, $compile, $filter, $http, $location, $route, $timeout, fetch) {, simply adding $sce into the function (,,,) list got this working so I can use  $sce.trustAsResourceUrl. Having been thrown at an angular codebase without any AngJS training sure has been fun :-(...