# ng-click is not working - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-click

I have checked all the solutions available here, but it didn't help me.

I am trying to display a button from AngularJs to html, but `ng-click` is not working for `<a>` or `<button>` tags. I am working in Eclipse and it contains many built in modules. Please help me out. Below is the sample code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="contrl">
<a href="" ng-click="testFunc1()">Link1</a>
<div id="id1">Text1</div>
<p id="id2">Text2</p>
</div>

<script>
    function contrl($scope,$http,$location){
            xyz = '<button type="submit" ng-click="testFunc2()">Link2</button>';
            document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = xyz;

            $scope.testFunc1 = function() {
            document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = "abc";
            };
            $scope.testFunc2 = function() {
            document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = "xyz";
            };
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Only `ng-click` attribute is not working when I pass it through angularJs. Even `href` attribute is working in the same case. As i am using Eclipse all the required modules are already setup in different files. I was working with angularJs from two weeks and everything was working except when I faced this issue.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle of this code?

Comment: Where you declare your app and controller?

Comment: I agree with @JsIsAwesome. You haven't actually set up the Angular app or controller properly.  Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: Yes. This will not work unless you have angular app set up properly. I don't see where you are loading the Angular min files and all?

Comment: I have included the angular min file in my example. I was using it but missed to copy it here. Anyhow the result is same, ng-click is not working.

Comment: why are you bothering with `document.getElementById` instead of using Angular 2 way binding?

Comment: I tried using {{id3}} and $scope.id3 way, but it was directly printing whole html code in the web page. Any pointers to other ways would be helpful.

Comment: printing whole html code? huh? can you show an example of how you used angular binding expressions, and the result you received?

Comment: <body>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="contrl">
<a href="" ng-click="testFunc1()">Link1</a>
<div>{{id1}}</div>
<p>{{id2}}</p>
</div>

<script>
    function contrl($scope,$http,$location){
            xyz = '<button type="submit" ng-click="testFunc2()">Link2</button>';
            $scope.id1 = xyz;

            $scope.testFunc1 = function() {
             $scope.id2 = "abc";
            };
            $scope.testFunc2 = function() {
             $scope.id2 = "xyz";
            };
    }
</script>
</body>
Output is: <button type="submit" ng-click="testFunc2()">Link2</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is the most basic approach someone would follow.**Its not wrong, only problem is you seem to be using newer version of angular for development or you have forgot to include any.**

*Your application development pattern is not supported by the recent released versions of angular.*

I have used till 1.2.26, it works.

[Check demo here](http://jsbin.com/totakoxeta/1/edit?html,output)

You have also used innerHTML, as well document.getElementById.

These are not at all required. Read more about bindings and other best parts of angular.

Comment: In your demo, you have given ng-click="testFunc2()" for div element too. Hence it was working. Once i remove ng-click from div it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're up to, but something like this will work better:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="contrl">
<p><a href="" ng-click="testFunc1()">Link1</a></p>
<div id="id1">{{ val1 }}</div>
<p id="id2">{{ val2 }}</p>
</div>

<script>
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

  myApp.controller('contrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {

      $scope.val1 = "text1";
      $scope.val2 = "text2";

      $scope.testFunc1 = function(){
            $scope.val1 = 'New Value';              
      }

      $scope.testFunc2 = function(){      
            $scope.val2 = 'Second New Value';                         
      };
  }]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obviously you will need to include calls to get the angular libraries in!

Comment: My task is to send a button or anchor tag with ng-click attribute from angularJs to html. Your example will not solve my purpose.

Comment: Yup, but why? What are trying to achieve? Can you use an angular variable to show/hide dom elements with ng-show, rather than pushing HTML into the dom from angular?

Comment: My requirement is to display 'n' number of links (anchor or button tags), where i will fetch 'n' from database. As 'n' is not a definite number, i cannot define a particular number of links in html. So to start with i was trying to print at least one link in this way.

Answer (score 0):

that's because angular doesn't know about the ng-click you bring in with plain javascript.
so if you want to do it in the html, you can write your script like this:

```
    function contrl($scope){


        $scope.text = 'text2';
        $scope.testFunc1 = function() {
            $scope.text = "abc";
        };
        $scope.testFunc2 = function() {
            $scope.text = "xyz";
        };
};
```

if you still want to insert the html from the script then have a look here: [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)