# Angularjs importing html in templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am very new to angular.js my task is to output html into a template, I have looked around and found a referencing $scope and $sanitize and using the ng-bind-html directive to get this done, none of this has worked for me.

I am wondering what the best approach for this is.

My data currently is coming from a JSON file with a content field containing html:

eg:

```
{
    "title:"thisTitle",
    "content":"`<h1>Hello world</h1>`"
}
```

The controller I have is very simple I am getting the resource via a $http.get

```
$http.get('/data/posts.json').success(function(data) {
    blog.posts = data;
});
```

My template is also very simple, for brevity this is similar.

```
<div ng-app="blog">
    <div ng-controller="BlogController as blog">
        <div>
            <h1>{{blog.post[0].title}}</h1>
            <div>{{blog.post[0].content}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously this is all psudo code but my code follows pretty closely.

What I am looking for is a clear answer of how to implement html into templates in a simple way.

I have tried this method
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml among others, is there any way that will work for me?

Cheers,
Any help is appreciated.

### EDIT

examples below are real code

Main template

```
 <section id="content" ng-app="blog">
     <div ng-controller="BlogController as blog" id="blog" class="origin">
         <div class="pop">
             <div class="blog-listings">
                 <div class="post-section">
                     <p class="title">Featured posts</p>
                     <ul>
                         <post-listing ng-repeat="post in blog.posts | featuredPost"></post-listing>
                     </ul>
                 </div>

                 <div class="post-section">
                     <p class="title">Previous posts</p>
                     <ul>
                         <post-listing ng-repeat="post in blog.posts | previousPost"></post-listing>
                     </ul>
                 </div>
             </div>

             <post-item ng-repeat="post in blog.posts"></post-item>

         </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

blog item template

```
<div ng-show="blog.isSelected($index)" class="blog-page-post">
    <div class="individualBlogPost">
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <div class="blogAvatar"></div>
        <p class="postDetails">
            <span class="name">{{ post.author }}</span><br>{{ post.date * 1000 | date:'EEEE MMM d y' }}
        </p>
        <div ng-bind-html="post.content" class="blogPostContent">
        </div>
        <img alt="" src="/img/blog/brush-line-784x7.png" class="brushStroke " />
    </div>
    <div class="blog-buttons">
        <a href="./blog-validation-full.html" class="blog-back">View all blog posts</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

blog controller

```
 (function() {

     var app = angular.module('blog', ['post-filters']);

    app.controller('BlogController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
         var blog = this;

         this.posts = [];
         this.tab = 0;

         $http.get('/data/posts.json').success(function(data, status) {
             var first_featured = _.first(feHelpers.checkFeatured(data, true));

             blog.posts = data;
             this.tab = first_featured.id;
         });

         this.selectTab = function(setTab) {

             this.tab = setTab;
         }

         this.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
             return this.tab === checkTab;
         }
     } ]);

     app.directive('postListing', function() {
         return {
             restrict: 'E',
             templateUrl: 'ng-blog-listing.html'
         };
     });

     app.directive('postItem', function() {
         return {
             restrict: 'E',
             templateUrl: 'ng-blog-post-item.html'
         };
     });


 })();
```

The JSON resource

```
[
    {
        "id":0,
        "title":"post title 1",
        "date":"1425254400",
        "author":"use name a",
        "thumbnail":"/img/blog/blog-listing/blog-thumb-validation.png",
        "published":true,
        "featured":true,
        "content":"<h1>this is html</h1>"
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "title":"post title 2",
        "date":"1421712000",
        "author":"user name b",
        "thumbnail":"/img/blog/blog-listing/blog-thumb-thumb.png",
        "published":true,
        "featured":true,
        "content":"<h1>this is html</h1>"
    }
]
```

If I am missing anything else let me know.

Comment: what output do you get when you use `ng-bind-html`? it should work, perhaps you can show the syntax you are using and the output that is wrong?

Comment: It could be the `sanitize` causing the issue - you might want to try if bypassing sanitize altogether helps: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#show-me-an-example-using-sce-

Comment: @Claies I get no output when I use ng-bind-html

Comment: please provide real code, compiled and tested. It has not to be the real code, but a code to be able to reproduce the problem. Otherwise a good specific answer can hardly be made. Assuming possible solutions on pseudo code is not what this site is made for.

Comment: can you show an example of the syntax you are using for `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach real code has been added .

Comment: That appears like it should work, and almost looks ripped from the official Angular documentation on the subject.  Are you certain you aren't getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @Claies I assure you it's my code, I am now getting Error: [$sce:unsafe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$sce/unsafe but that can be fixed by using ng-bind-html-unsafe, with this though still no output.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply anything wrong with being from the documentation, I was suggesting that if it worked for them, it should work for you.... I'd have to set up a plunker and toy around with it more, I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is $sce, not sure why but I found a post here: [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs?rq=1) talking about a similar issue, if you include $sce as a dependency you can use the trustAsHtml method to reassign the html and it will allow it in the template.

```
$http.get('/data/posts.json').success(function(data, status) {
        var first_featured = _.first(feHelpers.checkFeatured(data, true));

        var newData = [];
        _.each(data, function(post){
            post.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(post.content);
            newData.push(post);
        });

        blog.posts = newData;
        this.tab = first_featured.id;
    });
```

Edit:

I have been looking into this more and found this blog post which helps explain this issue:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/09/10/a-journey-with-trusted-html-in-angularjs.aspx