# Typeof variable returns 'object', How do I get the object's name/type?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have a Javascript object from my Angular JS app stored in the variable 'hymn' below:

[image: Console output of the variable]

I want to print out the type of variable `hymn.body`, I tried `typeof hymn.body` but I got back `'object'` but how do I get `'TrustedValueHolderType'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the name property of your object's constructor function.

`hymn.body.constructor.name` should contain the object's name.

Comment: Can you let me know why body is showing 'Trustedvalueholdertype' instead of object ?

Comment: well, because the `name` property of the constructor contains the object's actual name, not its type. This is not the same as `typeof`.

Comment: No that's not my question my question was when OP type hymn why body is showing TrustedValueHolderType instead of body:object

Comment: Because that's how the developers of the browser's console decided to display it ;) if there would be just `body:object`, you'd know it's an object, but not which object. So by showing the actual name, you know it's an object AND you know the object's name.

Comment: not sure but it happened after I did this code `$scope.hymn.body = $sce.trustAsHtml(hymn.body);` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml

Comment: @frazras what is the purpose of this ?

Comment: Hymn.body is a string with html, in order to add that string to the dom, I was required to pass it through the trustAsHtml function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs