# HTML <br> tag is not rendering on page with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm developing an angularJS application and when I set a String value with `"<br>"` tag, it is not rendering as HTML tag and it prints as `"AA<br>BB"` on the page. So I change it to `"&lt;br&gt;"` that is also not rendered and print as `"AA&lt;br&gt;BB"`.

```
for(x=0; x < data.length ; x++ ){
    csf = csf + '<br> '+data[x].csf;
}

$scope.targetValue = csf;
```

and I use this value in HTML as :

```
<div class="fz-display-table-cell fz-col-3 fz-main-result">
   <small>CSF:{{targetValue}} </small>
</div>
```

what is the reason for not rendering this text and print the tag in page?

Comment: Check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-bind-html` for this but its not a good idea to generate HTML inside controller in angular and assign it a scope value, if you are doing so then you are not using true power of angular.

In this case, instead, you can use `ng-repeat`. see the below code

http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/5henysda/1/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="tcrtl">
        <div class="fz-display-table-cell fz-col-3 fz-main-result">
            CSF:
            <div ng-repeat="item in data"> 
                <br/> {{item.csf}} 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('tcrtl', function($scope){

    var data = [
        {
            csf: 'one'
        },
        {
            csf: 'two'
        }
    ]

    $scope.data = data;
});
```

Comment: great, this is working...small change was needed to avoid the front <br/>. just like " {{item.csf}} <br/>".

Comment: I attempted this solution, however this does not remedy a situation where <br/> tags are contained in data returned from the server, where the item is not an iterable object...what's the best method to convert already created <br/> tags into justified HTML markup?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ng-bind-html` to render HTML:

```
<div class="fz-display-table-cell fz-col-3 fz-main-result">
   <small>CSF: <span ng-bind-html="{{targetValue}}"></span></small>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, but I tried this does not show the value, blank instead!