# angularJs variable to Html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, coffeescript, instagram

Actually im searching about how i can transform my variable into Html, this variable contain a embed code from instagram.

in my controller

```
instaembed.controler "instaCtrl", ($scope, $http) ->
#instagram embed get example from insta
    $http.get ("http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/")
        .success(data) ->
           $scope.html = data.html
...
```

the result in `$scope.html` contain a blockquote with many `div` and image

i've tested it in the view (with `ngsanitize`), but it show only the text and not the image.

Anyone have an idea about how to get it ? :D

thank you (sorry for my english).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use Angular's built in *Strict Contextual Escaping* `$sce`

> `$sce` [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Then, in your controller:

```
instaembed.controler "instaCtrl", ($scope, $http, $sce) ->
#instagram embed get example from insta
    $http.get ("http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/")
        .success(data) ->
           $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.html);
...
```

Comment: Hello, it's working a little (but better than my old test xD), now i get the the text, but i still can't get the image/video of the the embed, i don't know if Sce is still blocking the image/video and the script inside the <blockquote> ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what might cause that issue... can you create a fiddle or plunker with the data from the response as dummy data?

Comment: Hello,
http://plnkr.co/edit/ePWwS4NHwTfRcxprlAtJ?p=preview

As you can see, the image/video don't appear T-T.

Comment: I've just checked the *Instagram* api and it seems that your `$http.get` link is the issue as that doesn't seem to be the way you get a media element from their *API*, so everything is fine in your code now, just look over their *API* again :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment

I'm a bit confused about their Api :
https://instagram.com/developer/embedding/#media_redirect

they give us an example to how to get the embed version of the post.
the link of the example :
http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/

This link redirect to : 
http://api.instagram.com/publicapi/oembed/?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/

with the good json, but i don't know why they don't show the image T-T

but thanks for your help, maybe i can find why i can't load image/video :) 

thank you

Comment: use media embeding - According to [Instagram's API site](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) a **GET /media/media-id** request for a video object returns a JSON object with the information you need in "data.videos".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ngBindHtml` directive.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

`<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="html"></div>`

Where `html` is your `$scope.html` variable. This will render inside `div` what your variable contains.

```js
function testCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.html = "<strong>Hello world!</strong>"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-app>
    <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="html"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
<span ng-bind-html="your scope variable"></span>
```