# AngularJS ngHref inside ngRepeat doesn't evaluate value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-href

I have the following markup:

```
<ul ng-if="item.children.length && item.open" class="fadeIn">
    <li ng-repeat="child in item.children" ng-show="child.visible">
        <a ng-href="#/{{ child.link }}">
            <span ng-bind-html="child.title"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The result, when the controller runs is a LI element containing a link, which contains a span, for each item in the list, which is the expected result.

**The problem is that when clicking the link, nothing happens since the link is empty (#/). It is as if {{ child.link }} is not evaluated.**

If i hardcode my preferred link (#/whatever), the routeProvider picks it up and it works.

I have even changed the name of the link parameter, to no avail.
The scope menu structure contains a 'link' parameter for each menu.

There are no error in the console

Why isn't {{child.link}} evaluated?

Comment: I have failed to mention that there are no errors

Comment: If the expression was not evaluated, the link would be `#/{{ child.link }}`. Since you have `#/`, it is evaluated, and the result of the evaluation is an empty string. That means the `child.link` is an empty string, or null, or undefined.

Comment: Can you create a **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/)**? recreate the problem.

Comment: I would expect that `{{child.link}}` is evaluated. But are you sure that, child.link has text in it. Perhaps you insert a second span bound to child.link. `<span ng-bind="child.title"></span>` to see if it is assigned.

Comment: I added a second <span ng-bind="child.link"> and it works.

Comment: Sorry I made a fault. not {{child.title}} I meant {{child.link}},. Sorry again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the 2nd time i have been had like this.
This code is within a django template, and i have forgotten to use a verbatim tag. That means that Django will evaluate the expression to nothing before angular can have a chance to process this.

Thanks for all your help,
D.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9ygq9bt4/) and made your code work:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <ul ng-if="item.children.length && item.open" class="fadeIn">
        <li ng-repeat="child in item.children" ng-show="child.visible"> <a ng-href="#/{{ child.link }}">
            <span ng-bind-html="child.title"></span>
        </a>   
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.item = {
        open: true,
        children:[{
            visible: true,
            link: 'MyFirst',
            title: $sce.trustAsHtml('<h1>First</h1>')
        }]
    }
});
```

The only problem I had was with `ng-bind-html`. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs) post.

Comment: I can see that your fiddle works, as far as i can see it's identical to my code, which is very frustrating since this is basic stuff. There is no html in my example, so $sce is not needed, but it still isn't working.

Comment: @sm0ke21 Sometimes one uses lnk as attribute in the item and link in html. To see such a misspelling is hard. And Javascript does not show you an error because the value of link is undefined which is translated to "" by angular.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer i included that 2nd span with a binding to child.link and it works. I have also changed the property name to something else. the ngBind works, but ngHref still doesn't

Comment: That's strange. Did you use something like handlebars templating wich also uses {{ }} as start and begin marks for its replacements?

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer That's exactly what's happening. I have answered my own question (further up) but i cannot accept it for another 2 days.

Comment: @sm0ke21 Sorry, I've seen your answer to late!