# Directives not working on dynamically loaded content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a weird situation. I created 2 directives in my application.

```
orgNavigation
menuEnhancer
```

`orgNavigation` is responsible to build the html structure and `menuEnhancer` is to apply DOM specific logic. Both working great with static data but when the dynamic data is introduced, menuEnhancer is not working.

To test the behavior of menuEnhancer, click on any menu item. It should bring popup, which is working fine in static loaded template. But for dynamic loaded template, popup is not working.

I am thinking it might be because `menuEnhancer` link is executing before the navigation items loaded. Can anyone help how to fix it?

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cvxlfJj6HyFvQyB62Wa6?p=preview)

Comment: Don't have time for a more complete answer but basically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Comment: Really recommend you don't mix jquery and angular like this if you can avoid it.