# angularjs not binding to backend generated binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I have an `C# MVC` tag helper, which generates menu items for me. However I want these `URLs` to be `dynamic` based on a value set by `angular`. So my backend generates a URL like this:

```
 /blah/blah/{{vm.value}}
```

If I have an angular controller which has a property of value, will the link be updated everytime the value changes. It's not working for me. angular seems to be ignoring the `{{vm.value}}` because it was generated on the `backend` and is not in my template.

Comment: It sounds like you might not be using the "controllerAs: 'vm'" bit inside of your router, but some code would help in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

In-controller:-

```
$scope.linkValue = "<a ng-href="/blah/blah/{{vm.value}}">Test</a>";
```

In-html:-

```
<div ng-bind-html="linkValue | sanitize"></div>
```

In-filter:-

```
app.filter("sanitize", ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(htmlCode){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
  }
}]);
```

[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)