# AngularJs Return HTML from Controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, ng-bind-html

I try to return some HTML code from my AngularJs controller to the html data.

This is path of my html :

```
<div align="right">
   {{chooseHtmlElement()}}">
</div>
```

And this is path of my AngularJs Controller:

```
   $scope.chooseHtmlElement= function () {
        var sum = $scope.chiQuadSum();
        if (isNaN(sum)) {
            return "";
        }
        if (sum > 17.00) {
            return "<i class=\"fa fa-minus-circle\" style=\"color:red;\"></i>";
        } else if (sum < 14.00) {
            return "<i class=\"fa fa-check-circle\" style=\"color:green;\"></i>";
        } else {
            return "<i class=\"fa fa-circle\" style=\"color:orange;\"></i>";
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I return these string, the element is not shown as html element, but as text which you can read. Is there any possibility returning these string as html element?

Answer (score 11):

While binding html on view in angular js you need to use `ng-bind-html` directive. But before binding html, you need to sanitize that `html` by using `$sce.trustAsHtml` method of `ngSanitize` module.

```
<div align="right" ng-bind-html="chooseHtmlElement() | trustedhtml"></div>
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('trustedhtml', 
   function($sce) { 
      return $sce.trustAsHtml; 
   }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

#### ngSanitize

There are 2 steps:

1. include the angular-sanitize.min.js resource, i.e.:
   `<script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>`
2. In a js file (controller or usually app.js), include ngSanitize, i.e.:
   `angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'ngSanitize'])`

[$refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971756/2599533)

Answer (score 0):

**For Sanitizing an html string**
, Include following module and js in your code,

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

angular.module('app', [
  'ngSanitize'
]);
```

Bind scope like,

```
<div align="right" ng-bind-html="chooseHtmlElement()"></div>
```

Comment: its a function call.. `ng-bind-html="chooseHtmlElement()"` should be it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning element from controller to HTML use $element to add/append content from controller to HTML. Find your DIV element using angular.element.

var tag = your return elements.

```
var ele = $compile(tag)($scope);
angular.element('div').append(ele);
```