# AngularJS - How do I add an HTML element through a handlebar ternary operation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

**Note:** By "handlebars" I don't mean Handlebars.js, I just mean the double curly braces.

---

I have a table, and in one of the columns I want to display the data, and an additional HTML element depending on the outcome of the ternary operation.

Here is my code for the td

```
<td>{{item.ProjectNumber}}{{item.DateSubmitted.toString().length > 0 ? null : <span class="error">Incomplete</span>}}</td>
```

If I don't try to make it an element (rather just display 'Incomplete'), it works fine. But when I do try to add that span, that whole piece of code is added to the td.

So how can I create an HTML element inside of the handlebars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the element and optionally hide it with [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

`<span class="error" ng-show="item.DateSubmitted.toString()">Incomplete</span>`

I would typically reserve using curly braces for providing data, not making decisions. If you absolutely *must* create the element inline like that, you'll need to tell your application to trust the HTML, as described [in this SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view).

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I came up with a different way of doing it.

```
<td>{{factsheet.ProjectNumber}}<span class="{{factsheet.DateSubmitted.toString().length > 0 ? 'hide-error' : 'error'}}">Incomplete</span></td>
```

I just made the span and put the ternary logic in the class attribute where the class `.hide-error` is `display:none`

Comment: You should better go the way Harris Weinstein described in his answer.