# Using Array.join('<br />')

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, string-formatting

Is there any reason this is not working ? :

```
this.categoriesId = $rootScope.categoriesList.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.id;
}).join('<br />');
this.categoriesName = $rootScope.categoriesList.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.name;
}).join('<br />');
```

and in the view :

```
<b>Categories ID :</b><br/><br/>
{{h.categoriesId}}
<hr>
<b>Categories Name :</b><br/><br/>
{{h.categoriesName}}
```

There is no line breaks, the `<br />` isn't interpreted.

How can I work around this ?

Comment: you mean that `<br />` is displayed as text ?

Comment: I'll suggest you to use `ng-repeat` directive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Angular escapes the HTML in your string before it inserts it into the DOM, in order to prevent XSS attacks.

### Messy Fix

Use the `ng-bind-html` directive to insert the HTML *as is*.

```
<span ng-bind-html="h.categoriesName"></span>
```

Make sure to include the [`$sanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) service, and `ng-bind-html` will automatically sanitize your string to make sure it's safe within its context.

### Clean Fix

Use `ng-repeat` to iterate over the list without needing to worry about inserting markup into your string.

```
<b>Categories Name :</b><br/><br/>
<span ng-repeat="name in categoriesList">
  {{name}}<br />
</span>
```

Comment: `$sce` does sanitize `ng-bind-html`. You haven't accounted for that. Answer is misleading

Comment: @charlietfl Updated.

Comment: also can't use it without sanitize included as it will throw error and output nothing. So realistically `Safe Fix` is still misleading

Comment: Yep, got it: "Make sure to include the $sanitize service"

Comment: Got it working with a slight modification : `<span ng-repeat="category in $root.categoriesList">
  {{category.name}}<br />
</span>`

Comment: @Ellone should really get away from using `$rootScope` to store your data.

Answer (score 1):

`{{}}` is only interpreted as text , not html

Use `ng-repeat` , there is no need to parse array to html

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<b>Categories Name :</b><br/><br/>
<span ng-bind-html="h.categoriesName"><span>
```

Or create map and join filter:

```
app
.filter('map', function () {
    return function (arr, prop) {
        return arr.map(function (item) {
            return item[prop];
        });
    };
})
.filter('join', function () {
    return function (arr, sep) {
        return arr.join(sep);
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<span ng-bind-html="categoriesList | map: 'name' | join '<br/>'"><span>
```