# How to do a logic operation in Angular Template

Tags: angularjs

All:

I wonder how can I set a OR operator on a HTML string in Angualar Template, something like:

```
<div>{{value || <h6>No Header for now.</h6>}}</div>
```

The logic is if value is a string but not undefined, we show the value text, otherwise we show a error "No Header for Now" wrapped up by `<h6>`.

I do not know why this expression can not be correctly interpreted?

Thanks

Comment: Hello! Please accept my answer if it solves your problem. :) [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170863)

Comment: @GG. Thanks, I gave the UPVOTE to the answer, cos it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

```
<div ng-if="value">value</div>
<div ng-if="!value"><h6>No Header for now.</h6></div>
```

You can add specific attributes (e.g. `class`) and/or directives (e.g. `ng-click`) on each `<div>`.

The problem with using a single element is that you have to repeat your condition several times:

```
<div ng-class="{ value: 'class1', !value: 'class2' }"
     ng-click="value ? action1() : action2()"
     ng-bind-html="value || html">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also how I solve it right now, just currious how to do it in the way in my question

Comment: Ok nice! I edited my answer to add the disadvantage in my opinion to hold a condition with a single element. Hope it could help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a string, not an expression: `<h6>No Header for now.</h6>` is an invalid js expression. `'<h6>No Header for now.</h6>'` is a string and can be displayed in the  {{ }}.

`<div>{{value || '<h6>No Header for now.</h6>' }}</div>`

or

`<div>{{value != null ? value : '<h6>No Header for now.</h6>' }}</div>`

I'm convinced the 2nd works.

**EDIT:**

If you want to add html code in the {{ }}, it is another problem. See [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view), the filter 'sanitize' in 2nd answer should help you ( call `{{ '<h1>test</h1>' | sanitize }}` and it should work.

**EDIT 2:**

In a js file:

```
angular.module('yourapp')
.filter("sanitize", ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(htmlCode){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
  }
}]);
```

In view:

`<div>{{value || '<h6>No Header for now.</h6>' | sanitize }}</div>`

In dont know if you need 'ngResource' to use $sce, if it doesn't work, you will have to install angular-resource :/

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I must miss something, when I use yours, it just show the expression as plain text( but the h6 style works )

Comment: Thanks, could u show me what it looks like in my case?