# Html isn't recognizing the tags that Angularjs spitting out

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Angular

```
    $scope.name = "<h1>John Doe</h1>"
```

HTML

```
    <div>{{name}}</div>
```

Outputs:

```
    <h1>John Doe</h1>
```

How do I make it so Html recognize the tags that I'm spitting on the page.

Comment: Did you even bother to write the full code? Or at least `ng-app` code? But you are expecting us to find out the issue?

Comment: Sorry thought that were a given. My ctrl is connecting if it outputs the whole string.

Comment: @VictorLe check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way would be:

```
$scope.name = 'John Doe';
```

HTML:

```
<div><h1>{{name}}</h1></div>
```

I don't know why would you set html tags in your variables if you really really don't need to.

**EDIT according to comment:**

In the case you need to use html tags in your templates, please see this answer on SO: [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view)

I'm not going to duplicate the answer because it's explained very well in that answer.

Comment: I was grabbing it from the database. So the data included the html tags

Comment: Ok, in that case please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much it works now. I thought i was going crazy that I couldn't figure this out.. lmfao.

Comment: Hehe, no problem. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<h1 ng-bind-html-unsafe="name"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<div ng-if="name" ng-bind-html="name"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't spit out anything on the screen with this method

Answer (score 0):

```
<b>
$scope.renderHtml = function(html_code)
{
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
};
HTML:

<p ng-bind-html="renderHtml(value.button)"></p></b>
```