# How to highlight data if search text matched with available text in the array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have `$scope.data` that is already displaying to the screen using `ng-repeat` , I have a input where user can search from `$scope.data` , So i created filter if user search text matched with `$scope.data` highlight that text ,its not throwing any exception but also not highlighting the text, I am fairly new to angularjs filters help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

ctrl.js

```
$scope.data = ["Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text", "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"];
```

main.html

```
<div class="row search-input-margin">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="search">Search Logs:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" ng-model="vm.searchLog">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul style="list-style: none;">
                    <li ng-repeat="message in data track by $index"><span><strong>Log:</strong></span><span>{{message}}</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <!-- filter code -->
                    <div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:vm.searchLog"
                         ng-bind-html="item | highlight:vm.searchLog">
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

filter.js

```
angular.module('App').filter('highlight', function($sce) {
        return function(text, phrase) {
            if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
                '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
        }

    });
```

Comment: Suggest you create a simple plunker demo that reproduces this

Comment: sorry not authorized there

Comment: huh? it's a free site and requires no login or registration even

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing style for the `.highlighted` class

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = ["Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text", "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy"];
});

app.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
  return function(text, phrase) {
    if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gi'),
      '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
  }

});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  font-weight: bold
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController as vm">

  <div class="row search-input-margin">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="search">Search Logs:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" ng-model="vm.searchLog">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <!-- filter code -->
    <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter: vm.searchLog" ng-bind-html="item | highlight:vm.searchLog">
    </li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: when i have multiple logs for user to search its throwing error `angular.js:13920 Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: 0`

Comment: when $scope.data has multiple string like in my question its throwing error filter notarray not sure why.

Comment: i had track by $index on ng-repeat it should be on filter that resolved the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:vm.searchLog"
         ng-bind-html-unsafe="item | highlight:vm.searchLog">
</div>
```

Why don't you use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` here? and if you are using `ng-bind-html` are you loading `angular-sanitize.min.js`

A more detailed link here: 
[AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view)

Comment: I have `ngSanitize` in my module yes unsafe is better approach but i still do not see any highlighted text once i start typing in input .