# Using Angular 1.x with require() syntax to inject a template into a component via controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm using angular 1.x with es6 and webpack, following this tutorial: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/.

The author requires templates through `template: require('./home.html')`.

I want to inject a template into a component via a controller through this method, but it's not working:

```
export default class MyController {
    constructor() {
        this.templateUrl = require('./templates/foo.html');
    }
}

export const myComponent = {
    bindings: {
        templateUrl: '<'
    },
    template: '{{$ctrl.templateUrl}}'
}
```

This renders the html as a string, e.g. `<p>Some template</p>`. I imagine there must be an easy way to remedy this problem without having to use `ng-bind-html`.

I've also tried:

```
export default class MyController {
    constructor() {
        this.templateUrl = './templates/foo.html';
    }
}

export const myComponent = {
    bindings: {
        templateUrl: '<'
    },
    template: require('{{$ctrl.templateUrl}}')
}
```

results in `Cannot find module "{{$ctrl.panelUrl}}"`.

Comment: It should be `template: require('./templates/foo.html')`. `template: '{{$ctrl.templateUrl}}'` is very inefficient and also doesn't make sense.

Comment: The idea is to have the component as a generic wrapper for html posts. Any suggestions on best practices for this?

Comment: This question seems to clear it up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view