# Use regex to bold the word in search result which match the search query

Tags: jquery, angularjs, regex, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-app

I have stored input text value into a variable with id name=search-query.
And then I am searching through the JSON data to find any matching result and then output the result on the screen.
Is there a way which I can bold the word which match the search-query.val?

```
<body ng-app="products" ng-controller="ctrl"> 

 <input type="text" id="search-query" name="query" placeholder="Enter product name"></input>
 <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="result in searchResult|orderBy:order:reverse" >  
          <td >
               <a ng-href="{{result.link}}" target="_blank">
                    <span ng-bind="result.name" target="_blank"></span> 
                </a>
          </td>
          <td  ng-bind="result.type"></td> 
        </tr>  
 </tbody> 
</body>

var app2 = angular.module('products', []);
app2.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {  
$scope.searchResult = []; 
$scope.submit = function(){  
    var search = $("#search-query").val();
    $.each(json.products, function(i, v) {
         var regex = new RegExp(search, "i");

         if (v.name.search(regex) != -1) {  

              // For the following line, is there a way which I can bold the word which match the search-query.val?
              var name = v.name.replace(search, "<b>search</b>");   // doesn't work

              $scope.searchResult.push({ name:name, type: v.type, link: v.url }); 
              return;
          } 
});   
}
```

Comment: At first, why are you using jQuery for this? Also, you should use `ngBindHtml` to render the HTML, instead of just `strings`.

Comment: i tried ngBindHtml but cannot output the answer. Do you have ways to improve it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `$&` backreference that returns the whole match value, but also pay attention that the first argument to `replace` method is a RegExp, not the `search` string:

```
var name = v.name.replace(regex, "<b>$&</b>"); 
                                     ^^
```

Demo:

```js
var search = "DOM";
var s = "No dom here";
var regex = new RegExp(search, "i");
if (s.search(regex) != -1) {  
   document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + s.replace(regex, "<b>$&</b>") + "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: how do you get the < b> to print without it becoming HTML?

Comment: Do you mean in the post? It is part of the code (4-space indented lines). Else, you need to use `\`` backticks.

Comment: Thanks, I was putting it in `<code>` and I thought it would interpret it literally.

Comment: `<code>` is best when you need to apply code formatting style to spaces.

Comment: For search query of 'a', in the result, it is printing   Germ<b>a</b>n  Funds. I does not want the word <b> to print out, instead I want like a to be bold. I'm using angular JS for the code.

Comment: Try `.trustAsHtml()` in the controller to convert the html string. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10971756/3832970

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that

`var name = v.name.replace(search,"<b>search</b>");`

should be

`var name = v.name.replace(search,"<b>" + search + "</b>");`

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: For search query of 'a', in the result, it is printing Germ<b>a</b>n Funds. I does not want the word <b> to print out, instead I want like a to be bold. I'm using angular JS for the code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
content=document.getElementById("content");

content.innerHTML=content.innerHTML.replace(/search/gi,"<b>$&</b>");
```

```html
<div id="content">This my search text</div>
```

Try this one

```
v.name.innerHTML=v.name.innerHTML.replace(/search/gi,"<b>$&</b>");
```

Comment: It didn't work. because I am output the answer in the ng-app element. It is reading the <b> as in html word