# How to append anchor element to div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I work on my angularjs project.

I have this string in my controller:

```
"<a href="http://waze.to/?navigate=yes&ll=72.0274, 564.7814"  target="_blank">Open In Waze</a>"
```

And I have this div in my template:

```
 <div id="wazeArea" ng-init="editor.appandWazeLink(editor.siteId)"><i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

How can append anchor element above to div to make it clickable?

Comment: You want to make the whole div clickable, or you want to add the link inside the div? The later would be just something like $("#wazeArea).html(string);

Comment: Thank you for the answer I brief updated mu question can you see it?

Comment: Incidentally you may want to encode that URL in the href of your `<a>` element.

Answer (score 1):

This frustrated me a few times as well.  You should be able to just embed the string name into it like this:

```
var htmlStringFromController = "<a href="http://waze.to/?navigate=yes&ll=72.0274, 564.7814"  target="_blank">Open In Waze</a>";
```

And then call it from there.

```
<div id="wazeArea" ng-init="editor.appandWazeLink(editor.siteId)">{{htmlStringFromController}}</div>
```

The problem here is that angular doesn't want to inject raw HTML, right?  So you can use $sce to accomplish that ([AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view))

But the question is, could you just inject the URL into an anchor tag that already exists in the div?  Like this:

```
// controller code:
var URLFromController = "http://waze.to/?navigate=yes&ll=72.0274, 564.7814";
```

And then use this in the view, only displaying it if URLFromController is truthy.

```
<div id="wazeArea" ng-init="editor.appandWazeLink(editor.siteId)">
    <a ng-if="URLFromController" href="{{URLFromController}}" target="_blank">Open in Waze</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree, if it's an angular app, do it the angular way!!

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("wazeArea").appendChild(Anchor element in single quotes ' ');

You can use single quotes while making html string. It can allow double quotes inside that without need of escape characters

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1. get the parent of the div
// 2. append the anchor to it
$("#wazeArea").parent().append($(string));
// 3. move the div inside of the anchor by appending it
$("#id_of_a").append($("wazeArea"));
```