# HTML string sent as object value does not render on client

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hoping anyone could help...

I am sending an object value like

`{"message": "< img src='aaaa' />"}` from my node `API` to `AngularJS`.

On my client side I wish to call only `{{message}}` to display the rendered `img` attribute. Unfortunately, it renders `< img src= 'aaaa' />`.

I believe since the object value is a string, it renders the whole as a string --  `< img src= 'aaaa' >`

How to overcome the scenerio?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see this SO question. It shows you how to bind a string as HTML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view

Comment: Instead you can even send only src like : {"message": "aaaa"}, and then give it to img in our view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngSanitize` to render `HTML` you have got from the server. It basically sanitizes(determine its safe to render in UI) your `HTML` before it renders it in UI.

Include `angular-sanitize.js` in your scripts

```
<div ng-bind-html="msg.message"></div>
```

and include `ngSanitize` as a module dependency.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cASDlDFj2YIB3uclbsYx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/m2mKDur1qQdckaWa71eQ?p=preview)

You are returning JSON data. As far as I understood, you want to display the `key`, not the `value`.

**HTML:**

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    {{key}}
 </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 $scope.data = {"message": "< img src='aaaa' />"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $sce.trustAsHtml() in the controller to convert the html string.

```
$scope.datas=$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.data.message);
```

Then in your view, use ng-bind-html to binding html.

```
<div ng-bind-html="datas">
```

Check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tojopaul/78guby4L/1/)