# How can I handle html code sent by Json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this data from a json, it's html code, how can I print it like html because it only seems to print it as a String:

```
   "content": "Más pruebas\u003cbr /\u003e\n\u003cbr /\u003e\n\u003cdiv class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"\u003e\n\u003ca href=\"https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CK43Mn516s4/WEmWGS9eoaI/AAAAAAAASg0/k4213387TNA0XInyTNgqaqEn4YYanzCZgCLcB/s1600/Monsters-Inc-Concept-Art.jpg\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"\u003e\u003cimg border=\"0\" height=\"174\" src=\"https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CK43Mn516s4/WEmWGS9eoaI/AAAAAAAASg0/k4213387TNA0XInyTNgqaqEn4YYanzCZgCLcB/s200/Monsters-Inc-Concept-Art.jpg\" width=\"200\" /\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\n\u003ca href=\"http://google.com/\"\u003eGoogle\u003c/a\u003e",
```

I'm using angularjs 1.x

Thank you all!

Comment: You need to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: Can you provide the code that get and print this string ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view)

Comment: Seems like he just wants to print, not inject into his DOM. Here is a tool for being able to format such things: https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify

Comment: A simple call to `console.log` seems to print the output just fine...

Comment: See [this Demo on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/LaitovIRk9qt7EafPMmE?p=preview) to see the HTML both raw and rendered forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are receiving HTML code from your data source you should use the $sce service to escape it. Use

```
$sce.trustAsHtml(data)
```

Here is a plunker to demonstrate with your data which then displays the string as HTML:

https://plnkr.co/edit/LXLHhXCJ4zEZhFJSeT5W?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<div html="scopeVariable"></div>
```