# Can't inject HTML into an angular page

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to inject html into an angular page

My controller starts with:

```
myapp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $sce) {

$scope.renderHtml = function(html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
};
$scope.pgf = "<p>Hello</p>";
```

And on my HTML page I have:

```
<div class="intro"> AA {{renderHtml(pgf)}} AA </div>
```

And in the browser, I see:

```
AA <p>Hello</p> AA
```

Where what I want is

```
AA
Hello
AA
```

Is this a version problem- how do pick a consistent set of versions?  (If I just raise the versions, I get all sorts of errors...)

Comment: did you try ng-bind-html="varInScope", and storing the return of renderHtml into varInScope ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `ng-bind-html` ([angular ngBindHtml docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)) to bind HTML content...

*CONTROLLER*

```
function myCtrl($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.renderHtml = function(html_code) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
    };

    $scope.pgf = "<p>Hello I'm a Bear</p>";
}
```

*HTML*

```
<div ng-bind-html="renderHtml(pgf)"></div>
```

*Additionally, here you are a working [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/igfRF4xxLLINs6U6lbsx?p=preview) with your example.*

Comment: Thanks. This works, but so does (for me) without the function call:  <div ng-bind-html="pgf"></div>

Answer (score 1):

So your Angular code works but you didn't place your html binding in the right place.
You can't set a function inside angular binding `{{ function }}`

So in your HTML should say `<div ng-bind-html="trustHTML(pgf)"></div>`

Comment: Thanks! This works, but the trustHTML() function is not needed.
That is, it works with and without wrapping the inserted html.
The key is to put it in the ng-bind-html attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive in module `ng`. It provides a secure way of binding content to an HTML element.

**Syntax :**

```
<element ng-bind-html="expression"></element>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.renderHtml = function(html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
  };

  $scope.pgf = "<h1>Hello I'm a Bear</h1>";
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="renderHtml(pgf)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but the trustHTML() function is not needed.
That is, it works with and without wrapping the inserted html.
The key is to put it in the ng-bind-html attribute. This works:

<div ng-bind-html="pgf"></div>