# Angular js, how to append html inside div? (using controller)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, append

i'm trying to append inside the div **"otherfield"**, a directive element,

using while loop in the controller, who is binded to html using **updateBoxes** function:

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" min="2" class="form-control" id="numero_campi" ng-model="numerovoices" ng-change="updateBoxes(numerovoices)">

<div id="otherfield"></div>
```

**JS**

```
//DIRECTIVE
app.directive("listDirective", function() {
return {
    restrict:  'E',
    template : "<h1>This will repeated!</h1>"
};

$scope.updateBoxes = function(param){
    var el = document.getElementById('otherfield');
    var i = 0;
    while (i < param) {
        angular.element(el).append('<list-directive></list-directive>');
        i++;
    }   
}
```

I'm doing right? it do't work for me...

Comment: Does it do anything? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

For binding in Angular 1.x, you can use ng-bind-html for binding string as HTML.

```
<div ng-bind-html="thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml"></div>
```

You can also use $sce service for that.Use $sce.trustAsHtml() in the controller to convert the html string.

```
$sce.trustAsHtml('<list-directive></list-directive>')
```

Do check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view) for more information